# Convert seconds to hh:mm:ss in Python

Tags: python, django, time

How do I convert an int (number of seconds) to the formats **mm:ss** or **hh:mm:ss**?

I need to do this with Python code (and if possible in a Django template).

Answer (score 226, accepted):

I can't believe any of the many answers gives what I'd consider the "one obvious way to do it" (and I'm not even Dutch...!-) -- up to just below 24 hours' worth of seconds (86399 seconds, specifically):

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(12345))
'03:25:45'
```

Doing it in a Django template's more finicky, since the `time` filter supports a funky time-formatting syntax (inspired, I believe, from PHP), and also needs the datetime module, and a timezone implementation such as pytz, to prep the data. For example:

```
>>> from django import template as tt
>>> import pytz
>>> import datetime
>>> tt.Template('{{ x|time:"H:i:s" }}').render(
...     tt.Context({'x': datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(12345, pytz.utc)}))
u'03:25:45'
```

Depending on your exact needs, it might be more convenient to define a custom filter for this formatting task in your app.

Comment: while it's a minor issue, which is possibly irrelevant for the OP `time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(864001))` return a nasty surprise.

Comment: Yep, only works up for one day -- as does your solution of course, which breaks down differently instead of "wrapping around", since `str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400))` says "1 day";-)

Comment: :) I don't think that my solution *breaks down*, it still provides the most-readable output, since OP hasn't participated in the discussion around here, I'm free to assume that that's exactly what he wants.

Comment: Re *"...any of the many answers"*: Do you mean *"...none of the many answers"*?

Comment: As @AlexMartelli says, this doesn't work correctly if the number of seconds is more than a day. Also, `str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=<number>))` is more elegant

Comment: I don't get the 'dutch' thing :(
Also, I'm not dutch either.

Answer (score 116):

```
>>> a = datetime.timedelta(seconds=65)
datetime.timedelta(0, 65)
>>> str(a)
'0:01:05'
```

Comment: h:mm:sss isn't hh:mm:ss.

Comment: It doesn't answer his question, or offer anything that would lead him to a good answer to his question--at best you'd have to manually prepend a 0 or strip off "0:", which isn't a good solution at all (depends on timedelta.__str__ behavior which isn't specified anywhere as far as I know, so it could change).  So, yes.

Comment: i think you're just missing the point, OP needs number of seconds in **readable** format. that's what matters.

Comment: @Glenn: Dude, you're killing me from up on your idealistic high horse there.  It *does* answer his question, even if it's not the model of perfection.  (Manually having to append or prepend a "0" is not exactly an onerous burden.)

Comment: He didn't say "format it something like this", he gave specific formats.  I can't count the times I've formatted that way.  Editing the string means you're depending on the specific behavior of timedelta's string formatting (if s[0:2] == "0:": ...), which is a bad idea.  Maybe timedelta won't decide to format it as "h.mm.ss" in some locales now, but nothing says it can't in the future.  It's simply a poor approach.

Comment: I really like this, because it can cope with seconds > one day in a nice way and can even handle fractions of seconds: `str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=1111111.11))` results in '12 days, 20:38:31.110000'. Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: So, I found this trying to solve the question, and this worked perfect for me.

1106236 seconds became "12 days, 19:17:16"

Comment: Also see [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666)

Answer (score 29):

Read up on the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) module.

SilentGhost's answer has the details my answer leaves out and is reposted here:

```
>>> a = datetime.timedelta(seconds=65)
datetime.timedelta(0, 65)
>>> str(a)
'0:01:05'
```

Comment: @sth: SilentGhost has the deets.

Comment: I don't think anything in datetime does what he wants.  There's nothing like timedelta.strftime, so even if he stores his "number of seconds" as a timedelta (which he probably should), he'd still have to do the formatting himself.  Converting it to a time would be a hack, since he does seem to have an amount of time (timedelta) and not a time of day (time).

Comment: @Glenn: What's wrong with the str() representation?

Comment: @Glenn: from the question it's quite clear that formatting requirement is rather fluid. And it's much easier to just convert to string and be happy with `h:mm:ss` then to multiply dirty hacks  trying to get `hh:mm:ss`.

Comment: His question doesn't look fluid to me; it asks how to convert seconds to two specific formats, and almost everyone is responding with answers that simply don't do what he asked.  Formatting this as he asked does not require anything approaching a hack.

Comment: @GlennMaynard If "hh" is required, a simple `.zfill(7)` will take care of it.

Answer (score 27):

Code that does what was requested, with examples, and showing how cases he didn't specify are handled:

```
def format_seconds_to_hhmmss(seconds):
    hours = seconds // (60*60)
    seconds %= (60*60)
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return "%02i:%02i:%02i" % (hours, minutes, seconds)

def format_seconds_to_mmss(seconds):
    minutes = seconds // 60
    seconds %= 60
    return "%02i:%02i" % (minutes, seconds)

minutes = 60
hours = 60*60
assert format_seconds_to_mmss(7*minutes + 30) == "07:30"
assert format_seconds_to_mmss(15*minutes + 30) == "15:30"
assert format_seconds_to_mmss(1000*minutes + 30) == "1000:30"

assert format_seconds_to_hhmmss(2*hours + 15*minutes + 30) == "02:15:30"
assert format_seconds_to_hhmmss(11*hours + 15*minutes + 30) == "11:15:30"
assert format_seconds_to_hhmmss(99*hours + 15*minutes + 30) == "99:15:30"
assert format_seconds_to_hhmmss(500*hours + 15*minutes + 30) == "500:15:30"
```

You can--and probably should--store this as a timedelta rather than an int, but that's a separate issue and timedelta doesn't actually make this particular task any easier.

Comment: You could shorten the calculations a bit with divmod.

Comment: Nope. Not pythonic at all.

Answer (score 16):

You can calculate the number of minutes and hours from the number of seconds by simple division:

```
seconds = 12345
minutes = seconds // 60
hours = minutes // 60

print "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes % 60, seconds % 60)
print "%02d:%02d" % (minutes, seconds % 60)
```

Here `//` is Python's integer division.

Answer (score 12):

If you use divmod, you are immune to different flavors of integer division:

```
# show time strings for 3800 seconds

# easy way to get mm:ss
print "%02d:%02d" % divmod(3800, 60)

# easy way to get hh:mm:ss
from functools import reduce
print "%02d:%02d:%02d" % \
    reduce(lambda ll,b : divmod(ll[0],b) + ll[1:],
        [(3800,),60,60])


# function to convert floating point number of seconds to
# hh:mm:ss.sss
def secondsToStr(t):
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d" % \
        reduce(lambda ll,b : divmod(ll[0],b) + ll[1:],
            [(round(t*1000),),1000,60,60])

print secondsToStr(3800.123)
```

Prints:

```
63:20
01:03:20
01:03:20.123
```

Comment: bugfix for secondsToStr: round milliseconds. replace "t*1000" with "round(t*1000)"

Answer (score 1):

Not being a Python person, but the easiest without any libraries is just:

```
total   = 3800
seconds = total % 60
total   = total - seconds
hours   = total / 3600
total   = total - (hours * 3600)
mins    = total / 60
```

Answer (score 1):

Just be careful when dividing by 60: division between integers returns an integer ->
12/60 = 0 unless you import division from future.
The following is copy and pasted from Python 2.6.2:

```
IDLE 2.6.2      
>>> 12/60
0
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 12/60
0.20000000000000001
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this a lot, you can precalculate all possible strings for number of seconds in a day:

```
try:
    from itertools import product
except ImportError:
    def product(*seqs):
        if len(seqs) == 1:
            for p in seqs[0]:
                yield p,
        else:
            for s in seqs[0]:
                for p in product(*seqs[1:]):
                    yield (s,) + p

hhmmss = []
for (h, m, s) in product(range(24), range(60), range(60)):
    hhmmss.append("%02d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s))
```

Now conversion of seconds to format string is a fast indexed lookup:

```
print hhmmss[12345]
```

prints

```
'03:25:45'
```

**EDIT:**

Updated to 2020, removing Py2 compatibility ugliness, and f-strings!

```
import sys
from itertools import product


hhmmss = [f"{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}"
             for h, m, s in product(range(24), range(60), range(60))]

# we can still just index into the list, but define as a function
# for common API with code below
seconds_to_str = hhmmss.__getitem__

print(seconds_to_str(12345))
```

How much memory does this take? `sys.getsizeof` of a list won't do, since it will just give us the size of the list and its str refs, but not include the memory of the strs themselves:

```
# how big is a list of 24*60*60 8-character strs?
list_size = sys.getsizeof(hhmmss) + sum(sys.getsizeof(s) for s in hhmmss)
print("{:,}".format(list_size))
```

prints:

```
5,657,616
```

What if we just had one big str? Every value is exactly 8 characters long, so we can slice into this str and get the correct str for second X of the day:

```
hhmmss_str = ''.join([f"{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}"
                      for h, m, s in product(range(24),
                                             range(60),
                                             range(60))])
def seconds_to_str(n):
    loc = n * 8
    return hhmmss_str[loc: loc+8]

print(seconds_to_str(12345))
```

Did that save any space?

```
# how big is a str of 24*60*60*8 characters?
str_size = sys.getsizeof(hhmmss_str)
print("{:,}".format(str_size))
```

prints:

```
691,249
```

Reduced to about this much:

```
print(str_size / list_size)
```

prints:

```
0.12218026108523448
```

On the performance side, this looks like a classic memory vs. CPU tradeoff:

```
import timeit

print("\nindex into pre-calculated list")
print(timeit.timeit("hhmmss[6]", '''from itertools import product; hhmmss = [f"{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}"
                     for h, m, s in product(range(24),
                                             range(60),
                                             range(60))]'''))
print("\nget slice from pre-calculated str")
print(timeit.timeit("hhmmss_str[6*8:7*8]", '''from itertools import product; hhmmss_str=''.join([f"{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}"
                     for h, m, s in product(range(24),
                                             range(60),
                                             range(60))])'''))

print("\nuse datetime.timedelta from stdlib")
print(timeit.timeit("timedelta(seconds=6)", "from datetime import timedelta"))
print("\ninline compute of h, m, s using divmod")
print(timeit.timeit("n=6;m,s=divmod(n,60);h,m=divmod(m,60);f'{h:02d}:{m:02d}:{s:02d}'"))
```

On my machine I get:

```
index into pre-calculated list
0.0434853

get slice from pre-calculated str
0.1085147

use datetime.timedelta from stdlib
0.7625738

inline compute of h, m, s using divmod
2.0477764
```

Comment: This is not only wasteful of memory, but also unpleasant to read and unlikely to serve any kind of performance improvement.

Comment: Wow, it has been almost 10 years since I wrote this, sometimes frivolous answers can give some opportunities for learning some new things - thanks for the comment!

Answer (score -2):

Besides the fact that Python has built in support for dates and times (see bigmattyh's response), finding minutes or hours from seconds is easy:

```
minutes = seconds / 60
hours = minutes / 60
```

Now, when you want to display minutes or seconds, MOD them by 60 so that they will not be larger than 59

Comment: minutes is modulo 60, so it's always < 60, so hours == 0...

Comment: Oops, sorry, meant to do that step afterwards... will fix

Comment: At the very least provide the specific code to implement the modulus.    This answer come across to me as flippantly saying, "hey, there are 60 seconds in a minute--in case you didn't know."