# Django filter for converting the number of seconds into a readable form

Tags: python, django, format, seconds

I have model:

```
class Track(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    length = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

where length is the duration of track in seconds

I have template:

```
{% for track in tracks %}
{{track.artist}} - {{track.title}} {{track.length}}
{% endfor %}
```

How can I convert a length in the readable form, ie 320 seconds should be displayed as 5:20, 3770 as 1:02:50?

Forgive sorry for bad english.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/775049/python-time-seconds-to-hms

Comment: link to an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384406/python-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss

Comment: @gladysbixly - thanks for the link! I like the second answer & will use it in the future: `datetime.timedelta(seconds=3770).__str__()`. Fantastic!