# Logging execution time with decorators

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-decorators, functools

After I tried unsuccessfully for a while, I am seeking help from this miraculous website. Now for my problem: I want to create a decorator that writes the elapsed execution time of a function (***during* the execution of the function**) into a logging file like:

```
@log_time("log.txt", 35)
def some_function(...):
    ...
    return result
```

and

```
from functools import wraps

def log_time(path_to_logfile, interval):
    ...
```

so that `log.txt` would look something like

```
Time elapsed: 0h 0m 35s
Time elapsed: 0h 1m 10s
Time elapsed: 0h 1m 45s
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is a specification, not a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I figured something out in the end with threads. Thanks for all the suggestions!

```
import codecs, threading, time
from functools import wraps

def log_time(logpath="log.txt", interval=5):

    def log_time_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
            log_entries = 0
            with codecs.open(logpath, "wb", "utf-8") as logfile:
               start_time = time.time()
               t.start()
               while t.is_alive():
                   elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)
                   if elapsed_time > interval * log_entries:
                       m, s = divmod(elapsed_time, 60)
                       h, m = divmod(m, 60)
                       logfile.write("Elapsed time: %2dh %2dm %2ds\n" %(h, m, s))
                       log_entries += 1
        return wrapper
    return log_time_decorator
```

One disadvantage might be that you cannot easily retrieve the return value of the function (at least I haven't figured it out yet).

**EDIT1: Removed an unnecessary variable and added a nice format for logwriting (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384406/python-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss))**

**EDIT2: Even though other users rejected his edit, I want to include a version from [Piotr Dabkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1354439/piotr-dabkowski) because it works with a return-value:**

```
def log_time(logpath="log.txt", interval=5):

    def log_time_decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            RESULT = [None]
            def temp():
                RESULT[0] = func(*args, **kwargs)
            t = threading.Thread(target=temp)
            log_entries = 0
            with codecs.open(logpath, "wb", "utf-8") as logfile:
               start_time = time.time()
               t.start()
               while t.is_alive():
                   elapsed_time = (time.time() - start_time)
                   if elapsed_time > interval * log_entries:
                       m, s = divmod(elapsed_time, 60)
                       h, m = divmod(m, 60)
                       logfile.write("Elapsed time: %2dh %2dm %2ds\n" %(h, m, s))
                       log_entries += 1
            return RESULT[0]
        return wrapper
    return log_time_decorator
```

Answer (score 8):

I'll give you the basic overview about what you must do in order to accomplish this. The following is a decorator that accepts two parameters, and executes the function. The missing funcitonality is presented as comments, add them in:

```
def log_time(path_to_logfile, interval):
    def log(func):
        # 'wrap' this puppy up if needed 
        def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
            # start timing
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            # stop timing
            with open(path_to_logfile, 'a') as f:
                pass # functionality
        return wrapped
    return log
```

You can now decorate functions and the output is going to be written in `path_to_logfile`. So, for example, decorating `foo` here:

```
@log_time('foo.txt', 40)
def foo(i, j):
    print(i, j)

foo(1, 2)
```

Will take foo and execute it. You need to `time` it appropriately and write the contents to your file. You should experiment with decorators even more and read up on them, a nice article on [Decorators exist at the Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators).

Comment: But this will only log after the function terminates, right? I am looking for something that logs during the execution of the function though. Sorry if my question wasn't properly phrased.

Comment: @Kaleidophon decorators can't do that though. If you want logging *during* the execution you'll need to add that to the body of the function you're decorating. You can do that in a pseudo way by counting total time, dividing by interval and writting the appropriate number of lines to the file.

Answer (score 5):

Quickly put together but worked in a test with @timeit on a few functions.

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG, 
    filename='myProgramLog.txt', 
    format=' %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

import time                                                

def timeit(method):

    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        logging.debug('%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
              (method.__name__, args, kw, te-ts))
        return result

    return timed
```

Sources: https://www.andreas-jung.com/contents/a-python-decorator-for-measuring-the-execution-time-of-methods, https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter10/

EDIT: I find Python comes with a pretty good logging module; why re-invent the wheel?