# AttributeError issues with the decorator

Tags: python, recursion, decorator

I've been playing around reversing single-linked lists and all works fine but then I decided to add a decorator to time execution of functions. And now I get errors like this when I try to run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/cherp2/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/cherp2/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 78, in main
    print_ll(ll)
  File "C:/Users/cherp2/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 10, in wrapped
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/cherp2/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/PyCharmCE2020.3/scratches/scratch_7.py", line 37, in print_ll
    vals.append(str(node.val))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'val'
```

My decorator code is below. I checked and its pretty much the same as in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981602/logging-execution-time-with-decorators):

```
def func_time(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        t = dt.datetime.now()
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'{f.__name__} -- elapsed: {dt.datetime.now() - t}')
    return wrapped
```

Could the issues come because I'm using recursion in most of the functions? This is the linked list node definition and one of the erring functions:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import datetime as dt
from typing import Optional
import random


@dataclass(order=True)
class Node:
    val: int
    next: 'Node' = field()


def make_ll(n, head: Optional[Node] = None, node: Optional[Node] = None):
    if not head:
        head = Node(random.randint(0, 20), None)
        node = head
    node.next = Node(random.randint(0, 20), None)
    if n == 0:
        return head
    else:
        return make_ll(n-1, head, node.next)


@func_time
def print_ll(node: Node, vals: Optional[list] = None):
    if not vals:
        vals = []
    vals.append(str(node.val))
    if node.next:
        return print_ll(node.next, vals)
    else:
        vals.append('None')
        print(' -> '.join(vals))


def main():
    ll = make_ll(10, None)
    print('Original list: ')
    print_ll(ll)


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

*EDIT:*
Looks like it's definitely an issue with recursion. I tested the decorator on non-recursive functions and it works as expected:

```
@func_time
def add(l):
    running_sum = 0
    for a in l:
        running_sum += a
    return running_sum

>>> l = [i for i in range(10**6)]
>>> x = add(l)
Out: add -- elapsed: 0:00:00.052296
```

**EDIT2:**
Testing code in the question:

```
def main():
    # ll = make_ll(10, None)
    ll = Node(1, None)
    ll.next = Node(2, None)
    ll.next.next = Node(3, None)
    ll.next.next.next = Node(4, None)
    ll.next.next.next.next = Node(5, None)
    print('Original list: ')
    print_ll(ll)

    rev = reverse_ll(ll)
    print('Reversed list: ')
    print_ll(rev)

>>> main()

Out: 
Original list: 
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> None

Reversed list: 
5 -> 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1 -> None
```

Comment: I think the problem is your decorator ***isn't*** written properly (not recursion). However I can't test that theory because you haven't provided a [mre]. Please edit your question and add one.

Comment: I've appended  the code in the question to make it an MRE. I've also added an example in the EDIT section in the bottom that the decorator works fine with non-recursive functions.

Comment: The code you added doesn't produce the `AttributeError` shown in your question — although it doesn't do what the non-recursive does (nor what you want).

Comment: The second part of your comment is quite cryptic. What do you mean by: *it doesn't do what the non-recursive does (nor what you want)*

Comment: What part was unclear? The code in the version now in your question doesn't cause the error, but doesn't work properly and do what you want either. (There's a different fix for it — the decorator issue doesn't affect it.)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. The code in the question works fine without the decorator and produces correct results. Ans same goes for the parts not included in the question dealing with reversing the list - it all works fine. What exactly is not working properly in your opinion?

Comment: @martineau, I've added example that code works fine if I remove the decorator and prints expected result including the result of reversing (not included for brevity).

Comment: I meant the code did not time the function correctly. Will look at this again tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is quite embarrassing, but what happened was that I forgot to add a return statement to the decorator and so when it's used recursively, on the very first recursion it returns `None` and then recursion fails because `None` is not an acceptable input argument.

Simply put, this fixes all issues:

```
def func_time(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        t = dt.datetime.now()
        foo = f(*args, **kwargs)
        print(f'{f.__name__} -- elapsed: {dt.datetime.now() - t}')
        return foo
    return wrapped
```

Comment: Yes, that was the decorator problem I noticed when I made my initial comment under your question and will get rid of the `AttributeError`. However the decorator will time each recursive call to the the `print_ll()` function separately — which I doubt is what you would want to happen. _That's_ what my "cryptic" remarks were all about.

Comment: Oh yeah, but no, that actually was what I wanted - to measure the execution of each of recursive steps.