# How do I convert seconds to hh:mm:ss in django template

Tags: python, html, django, templates

So I have a dictionary called match. This has details of a match and one of the keys are game_time. If the game time is <= 10, the match is in draft. Else, I want to report the game time but the value its stored in is just in seconds.

```
                    {% if match.game_time <= 10 %}
                        drafting
                    {% else %}
                        {{match.game_time|date: "Z"}}
                    {% endif %}
```

Just gives me an error

```
Could not parse the remainder: ': "Z"' from 'match.game_time|date: "Z"'
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Use this formate for time

```
{{your_date_field|time:"h:i a"}}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me  for some reason. Nothing shows up Any ideas?

Comment: what in this **match.game_time** any time or number

Comment: its just a number. like 355. To me it means 355 seconds so I want to represent it as hh:mm:ss

Comment: see this it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384406/python-convert-seconds-to-hhmmss

Comment: in views convert second to time

Comment: I'm trying to do it in the template though. Is there no way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def millisec_to_time(millisec):
    d = datetime(1, 1, 1)+millisec
    if d.day - 1 == 0:
        return "{0}:{1}:{2}".format(d.hour, d.minute, d.second)
    else:
        return "{0}:{1}:{2}:{3}".format(d.day-1, d.hour, d.minute, d.second)
```

Try this to convert sec/msec to actual time.

Comment: is there no way to do it within the template?

Answer (score 0):

If you install mathfilters, add it to your install_apps, and load it into your template then you can do this.

```
{{ booking.duration|div:3600|floatformat:"2" }}
```