# Python human readable date difference

Tags: python, datetime

I have given date strings like these:

```
Mon Jun 28 10:51:07 2010
Fri Jun 18 10:18:43 2010
Wed Dec 15 09:18:43 2010
```

What is a handy python way to calculate the difference in days? Assuming the time zone is the same.

The strings were returned by linux commands.

*Edit:* Thank you, so many good answers

Comment: this looks an awful lot like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958844/human-readable-datetime-interval-to-datetime-timedelta-in-python/53231775 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string which also has interesting answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import datetime

def hrdd(d1, d2):
    """
    Human-readable date difference.
    """
    _d1 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d1, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    _d2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(d2, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
    diff = _d2 - _d1
    return diff.days # <-- alternatively: diff.seconds 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    d1 = "Mon Jun 28 10:51:07 2010"
    d2 = "Fri Jun 18 10:18:43 2010"
    d3 = "Wed Dec 15 09:18:43 2010"

    print hrdd(d1, d2)
    # ==> -11
    print hrdd(d2, d1)
    # ==> 10
    print hrdd(d1, d3)
    # ==> 169
    # ...
```

Answer (score 7):

Use [strptime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime).

Sample usage:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_date = datetime.strptime('Mon Jun 28 10:51:07 2010', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print my_date
```

**EDIT:**

You could also print the time difference in a human readable form, like so:

```
from time import strptime
from datetime import datetime

def date_diff(older, newer):
    """
    Returns a humanized string representing time difference

    The output rounds up to days, hours, minutes, or seconds.
    4 days 5 hours returns '4 days'
    0 days 4 hours 3 minutes returns '4 hours', etc...
    """

    timeDiff = newer - older
    days = timeDiff.days
    hours = timeDiff.seconds/3600
    minutes = timeDiff.seconds%3600/60
    seconds = timeDiff.seconds%3600%60

    str = ""
    tStr = ""
    if days > 0:
        if days == 1:   tStr = "day"
        else:           tStr = "days"
        str = str + "%s %s" %(days, tStr)
        return str
    elif hours > 0:
        if hours == 1:  tStr = "hour"
        else:           tStr = "hours"
        str = str + "%s %s" %(hours, tStr)
        return str
    elif minutes > 0:
        if minutes == 1:tStr = "min"
        else:           tStr = "mins"           
        str = str + "%s %s" %(minutes, tStr)
        return str
    elif seconds > 0:
        if seconds == 1:tStr = "sec"
        else:           tStr = "secs"
        str = str + "%s %s" %(seconds, tStr)
        return str
    else:
        return None

older = datetime.strptime('Mon Jun 28 10:51:07 2010', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
newer = datetime.strptime('Tue Jun 28 10:52:07 2010', '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
print date_diff(older, newer)
```

[Original source](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/412/) for the time snippet.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime("Mon Jun 28 10:51:07 2010", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
>>> b = datetime.datetime.strptime("Fri Jun 18 10:18:43 2010", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
>>> c = a-b
>>> c.days
10
```

Comment: This is the snippet used in the other answers

Comment: Yes, and as far as I can see, my answer predates the others (or the edits that incorporated those snippets). Not that it’s a very creative answer, you just need to read the docs...)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't along the same lines as the other answers, but it might be helpful to someone wanting to display something more human readable (and less precise). I did this quickly, so suggestions welcome.

(Note that it assumes `until_seconds` is the later timestamp.)

```
def readable_delta(from_seconds, until_seconds=None):
    '''Returns a nice readable delta.

    readable_delta(1, 2)           # 1 second ago
    readable_delta(1000, 2000)     # 16 minutes ago
    readable_delta(1000, 9000)     # 2 hours, 133 minutes ago
    readable_delta(1000, 987650)   # 11 days ago
    readable_delta(1000)           # 15049 days ago (relative to now)
    '''

    if not until_seconds:
        until_seconds = time.time()

    seconds = until_seconds - from_seconds
    delta = datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds)

    # deltas store time as seconds and days, we have to get hours and minutes ourselves
    delta_minutes = delta.seconds // 60
    delta_hours = delta_minutes // 60

    ## show a fuzzy but useful approximation of the time delta
    if delta.days:
        return '%d day%s ago' % (delta.days, plur(delta.days))
    elif delta_hours:
        return '%d hour%s, %d minute%s ago' % (delta_hours, plur(delta_hours), delta_minutes, plur(delta_minutes))
    elif delta_minutes:
        return '%d minute%s ago' % (delta_minutes, plur(delta_minutes))
    else:
        return '%d second%s ago' % (delta.seconds, plur(delta.seconds))

def plur(it):
    '''Quick way to know when you should pluralize something.'''
    try:
        size = len(it)
    except TypeError:
        size = int(it)
    return '' if size==1 else 's'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an improved version of date_diff() routine by @the_void. It will print difference in the following fashion depending on how much the difference is:

```
1d 
12 sec
30 min 12 sec
3h 30m 
5d 3h 30m
```

Here is the routine:

```
def date_diff(newer, older):
    if newer < older:
        return '-1'

    timeDiff = newer - older
    days = int(timeDiff.days)
    hours = int(timeDiff.seconds/3600)
    minutes = int(timeDiff.seconds%3600/60)
    seconds = int(timeDiff.seconds%3600%60)

    str = ""
    tStr = ""
    if days > 0:
        tStr = "d"
        str = str + "%s%s " %(days, tStr)        

    if hours > 0:
        tStr = "h"
        str = str + "%s%s " %(hours, tStr)
        
    if minutes > 0:
        if days == 0 and hours == 0:
            tStr = 'min'
            str = str + "%s %s " %(minutes, tStr)
        else:
            tStr = "m"
            str = str + "%s%s " %(minutes, tStr)
        
    if days == 0 and hours == 0:    
        if seconds >= 0:
            if days == 0 and hours == 0:
                tStr = "sec"               
                
                str = str + "%s %s" %(seconds, tStr)
            else:
                tStr = 's'
                str = str + "%s%s" %(seconds, tStr)
    
    return str
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.strptime("Mon Jun 28 10:51:07 2010", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y") - datetime.datetime.strptime("Fri Jun 18 10:18:43 2010", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")).days
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

resp = raw_input("What is the first date ?")
date1 = datetime.strptime(resp,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
resp2 = raw_input("What is the second date ?")
date2 = datetime.strptime(resp2,"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
res = date2-date1
print str(res)
```

For details on how to print a timedelta object better, you can see [this previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string).