# How can I produce a human readable difference when subtracting two UNIX timestamps using Python?

Tags: python, time, formatting

This question is similar [to this question about subtracting dates with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3132468/python-human-readable-date-difference), but not identical. I'm not dealing with strings, I have to figure out the difference between two epoch time stamps and produce the difference in a human readable format.

For instance:

```
32 Seconds
17 Minutes
22.3 Hours
1.25 Days
3.5 Weeks
2 Months
4.25 Years
```

Alternately, I'd like to express the difference like this:

```
4 years, 6 months, 3 weeks, 4 days, 6 hours 21 minutes and 15 seconds
```

I don't think I can use `strptime`, since I'm working with the difference of two epoch dates. I could write something to do this, but I'm quite sure that there's something already written that I could use.

What module would be appropriate? Am I just missing something in `time`? My journey into Python is just really beginning, if this is indeed a duplicate it's because I failed to figure out what to search for.

#### Addendum

For accuracy, I really care most about the current year's calendar.

Comment: By UNIX epoch date you mean the usual number of seconds since X?

Comment: How accurate do you want the month / year calculation to be?  It can get complicated since the number of days per month and per year can vary.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the wonderful [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) module and its [relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-ba5ffd4df8111d1b83fc194b97ebecf837add454) class:

```
import datetime
import dateutil.relativedelta

dt1 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(123456789) # 1973-11-29 22:33:09
dt2 = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(234567890) # 1977-06-07 23:44:50
rd = dateutil.relativedelta.relativedelta (dt2, dt1)

print "%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, %d minutes and %d seconds" % (rd.years, rd.months, rd.days, rd.hours, rd.minutes, rd.seconds)
# 3 years, 6 months, 9 days, 1 hours, 11 minutes and 41 seconds
```

It doesn't count weeks, but that shouldn't be too hard to add.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Expressing weeks as days isn't a problem.

Comment: Is there a simple way to display only the non 0 units and to pluralize automatically ? like "1 year, 2 minutes and 1 second"

Comment: @PierredeLESPINAY You can ternary the `rd.second` as a final printf argument and and replace the `s` in `seconds` with `%s`, it's either 's' or '' depending on plurality.

Answer (score 57):

A little improvement over @Schnouki's solution with a single line list comprehension. Also displays the plural in case of plural entities (like hours)

Import relativedelta

```
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
```

A lambda function

```
>>> attrs = ['years', 'months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']
>>> human_readable = lambda delta: ['%d %s' % (getattr(delta, attr), attr if getattr(delta, attr) > 1 else attr[:-1]) 
...     for attr in attrs if getattr(delta, attr)]
```

Example usage:

```
>>> human_readable(relativedelta(minutes=125))
['2 hours', '5 minutes']
>>> human_readable(relativedelta(hours=(24 * 365) + 1))
['365 days', '1 hour']
```

Comment: had to add 'microseconds' to `attrs` for really short times to avoid errors, but great method.

Comment: This also helps avoid creating datetime objects from timestamps when you can just store the epoch timings directly. So then you can say `relativedelta(seconds=(t1 - t0))`.

Answer (score 24):

I had that exact same problem earlier today and I couldn't find anything in the standard libraries that I could use, so this is what I wrote:

[humanize_time.py](https://github.com/liudmil-mitev/experiments/blob/master/time/humanize_time.py)

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

    INTERVALS = [1, 60, 3600, 86400, 604800, 2419200, 29030400]
    NAMES = [('second', 'seconds'),
             ('minute', 'minutes'),
             ('hour', 'hours'),
             ('day', 'days'),
             ('week', 'weeks'),
             ('month', 'months'),
             ('year', 'years')]

    def humanize_time(amount, units):
    """
    Divide `amount` in time periods.
    Useful for making time intervals more human readable.

    >>> humanize_time(173, 'hours')
    [(1, 'week'), (5, 'hours')]
    >>> humanize_time(17313, 'seconds')
    [(4, 'hours'), (48, 'minutes'), (33, 'seconds')]
    >>> humanize_time(90, 'weeks')
    [(1, 'year'), (10, 'months'), (2, 'weeks')]
    >>> humanize_time(42, 'months')
    [(3, 'years'), (6, 'months')]
    >>> humanize_time(500, 'days')
    [(1, 'year'), (5, 'months'), (3, 'weeks'), (3, 'days')]
    """
       result = []

       unit = map(lambda a: a[1], NAMES).index(units)
       # Convert to seconds
       amount = amount * INTERVALS[unit]

       for i in range(len(NAMES)-1, -1, -1):
          a = amount / INTERVALS[i]
          if a > 0:
             result.append( (a, NAMES[i][1 % a]) )
             amount -= a * INTERVALS[i]

       return result

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        import doctest
        doctest.testmod()
```

You can use `dateutil.relativedelta()` to calculate the accurate time delta and humanize it with this script.

Comment: I'm curious as to where you are getting your numbers for seconds in Weeks, Months, and  Years.

Comment: I wrote it as `[1, 60, 60*60, 24*60*60, 7*24*60*60 ... ]` originally to be more obvious but I thought that it looked long and annoying, so I changed it to this. The current code is merely the result from the multiplications.

Comment: How can we handle `amount` values that have decimal places? Eg: `humanize_time(60.5, 'seconds')` should give `1 minute, 0.5 seconds`

Answer (score 14):

```
def humanize_time(amount, units = 'seconds'):    

    def process_time(amount, units):

        INTERVALS = [   1, 60, 
                        60*60, 
                        60*60*24, 
                        60*60*24*7, 
                        60*60*24*7*4, 
                        60*60*24*7*4*12, 
                        60*60*24*7*4*12*100,
                        60*60*24*7*4*12*100*10]
        NAMES = [('second', 'seconds'),
                 ('minute', 'minutes'),
                 ('hour', 'hours'),
                 ('day', 'days'),
                 ('week', 'weeks'),
                 ('month', 'months'),
                 ('year', 'years'),
                 ('century', 'centuries'),
                 ('millennium', 'millennia')]

        result = []

        unit = map(lambda a: a[1], NAMES).index(units)
        # Convert to seconds
        amount = amount * INTERVALS[unit]

        for i in range(len(NAMES)-1, -1, -1):
            a = amount // INTERVALS[i]
            if a > 0: 
                result.append( (a, NAMES[i][1 % a]) )
                amount -= a * INTERVALS[i]

        return result

    rd = process_time(int(amount), units)
    cont = 0
    for u in rd:
        if u[0] > 0:
            cont += 1

    buf = ''
    i = 0
    for u in rd:
        if u[0] > 0:
            buf += "%d %s" % (u[0], u[1])
            cont -= 1

        if i < (len(rd)-1):
            if cont > 1:
                buf += ", "
            else:
                buf += " and "

        i += 1

    return buf
```

Example of use:

```
>>> print humanize_time(234567890 - 123456789)
3 years, 9 months, 3 weeks, 5 days, 11 minutes and 41 seconds
>>> humanize_time(9, 'weeks')
2 months and 1 week
```

Advantage (You don't need third parties!).

Improved from "Liudmil Mitev" algorithm. (Thanks!)

Comment: I like no new modules must be installed.

Comment: till week it is good, but the moment it starts calculating month and year, It became higly inaccurate, As per interval logic, your month is going to be 28 days and year is going to be 336 days.

Answer (score 13):

Check out the humanize package

https://github.com/jmoiron/humanize

```
import datetime

humanize.naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))

'a second ago'

humanize.naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600))

'an hour ago'
```

Comment: this should be an answer in 2020

Answer (score 9):

Old question, but I personally like this approach most:

```
import datetime
import math

def human_time(*args, **kwargs):
    secs  = float(datetime.timedelta(*args, **kwargs).total_seconds())
    units = [("day", 86400), ("hour", 3600), ("minute", 60), ("second", 1)]
    parts = []
    for unit, mul in units:
        if secs / mul >= 1 or mul == 1:
            if mul > 1:
                n = int(math.floor(secs / mul))
                secs -= n * mul
            else:
                n = secs if secs != int(secs) else int(secs)
            parts.append("%s %s%s" % (n, unit, "" if n == 1 else "s"))
    return ", ".join(parts)

human_time(seconds=3721)
# -> "1 hour, 2 minutes, 1 second"
```

If you want to separate the seconds part with an "and" do:

```
"%s and %s" % tuple(human_time(seconds=3721).rsplit(", ", 1))
# -> "1 hour, 2 minutes and 1 second"
```

Answer (score 7):

Here's a shorter one for interval in seconds and within a day (t<86400). Useful if you work with unix timestamps (seconds since epoch, UTC).

```
t = 45678
print('%d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds' % (t//3600, t%3600//60, t%60))
```

May be extended further (t//86400, ...).

Answer (score 5):

A very old question but I found this solution which seems to be very simple in Python3:

```
print(datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600))
# output: 1:00:00
print(datetime.timedelta(hours=360.1245))
# output: 15 days, 0:07:28.200000
```