# Python - Convert seconds from epoch time into human readable time

Tags: python, time

Originally I made this code to convert date into human readable time:

```
    a = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    b = datetime.datetime.now()
    c = b - a
    days, hours, minutes, seconds = int(c.days), int(c.seconds // 3600), int(c.seconds % 3600 / 60.0), int(c.seconds % 60.0)
    return days, hours, minutes, seconds
    EXAMPLE OUTPUT: 1 days, 4 hours, 24 minutes, 37 seconds
```

and I'm trying to make it using epoch time, but I have no idea on to make it calculate days hours and etc.

```
    a = last_epoch #last epoch recorded
    b = time.time() #current epoch time
    c = b - a #returns seconds
    hours = c // 3600 / 24 #the only thing I managed to figure out
```

Comment: This answer should help you out: [How can I produce a human readable difference when subtracting two UNIX timestamps using Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574329/how-can-i-produce-a-human-readable-difference-when-subtracting-two-unix-timestam)

Comment: @JohnZwinck no the question did not answer, I will get year 1970 if I convert seconds from last_epoch - time.time()

Comment: IMHO, a closer duplicate is this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574329/how-can-i-produce-a-human-readable-difference-when-subtracting-two-unix-timestam

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
a = last_epoch #last epoch recorded
b = time.time() #current epoch time
c = b - a #returns seconds
days = c // 86400
hours = c // 3600 % 24
minutes = c // 60 % 60
seconds = c % 60
```

Comment: Thank you! Best convenient way without using extra python modules

Answer (score 64):

```
import datetime
timestamp = 1339521878.04 
value = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: Best convenient way with less typing and more robustness to errors.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).isoformat()` is much more convenient than futzing with `strftime`