# python convert timedelta to meaningful string such as "1 hours"

Tags: python, python-3.x, timedelta

I want to convert a python timedelta object to an easy to read meaningful string

for example:

```
0 1:0:0 -> 1 hours
0 0:5:0. -> 5 minutes
2 0:0:0. ->. 2 days
```

any ideas how to do that?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I produce a human readable difference when subtracting two UNIX timestamps using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574329/how-can-i-produce-a-human-readable-difference-when-subtracting-two-unix-timestam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `timedelta` class, provides you `days`, `seconds`, `microseconds` property directly. But in order to get "hours" and "minutes" you can do some simple calculations yourself.

```
import datetime

d1 = datetime.datetime(2012, 4, 20, second=10, microsecond=14)
d2 = datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 20, second=8, microsecond=4)
delta = d1 - d2

print(delta)
print(delta.days)
print(delta.seconds)
print(delta.microseconds)
```

Divide seconds by 60 to get minutes, by 3600 to get hours

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at [humanize](https://pypi.org/project/humanize/) python library:

```
>>> humanize.naturaldelta(dt.timedelta(seconds=1001))
'16 minutes'
```