# Human-readable datetime interval to datetime.timedelta in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, intervals

I find myself needing to specify a timespan in a python configuration file a lot.

Is there a way that I can specify a more human readable timeframe (similar to PostgreSQL's Interval syntax) in a python configuration file with stdlib?  Or will this require a 3rd party lib?

**Clarification**  I'm not looking for anything in the `ConfigParser.ConfigParser` stdlib API specifically.  I guess what I really need is a way to go from human readable date/time interval to `datetime.timedelta` value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard library module for that. I wrote one that does that. You can install it, or adapt it to your needs.

The module is called [pycopia.timespec](http://code.google.com/p/pycopia/source/browse/trunk/aid/pycopia/timespec.py)

It converts strings such as "1day 3min" to seconds, as a float. It's easy to get a `datetime.timedelta` from that.

Answer (score 3):

I found a good answer to this in an [somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50961202/1174784). Turns out the [`humanfriendly`](https://pypi.org/project/humanfriendly/) library does that fairly well:

```
In [1]: import humanfriendly

In [2]: humanfriendly.parse_timespan('1w')
Out[2]: 604800.0
```

That's in seconds. To get a `timedelta` object, you can simply load that:

```
In [3]: from datetime import timedelta

In [4]: timedelta(seconds=humanfriendly.parse_timespan('1w'))
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(7)
```

Since humanfriendly also supports converting the other way, you can also do full round trip, which would look like:

```
In [5]: humanfriendly.format_timespan(timedelta(seconds=humanfriendly.parse_timespan('1w')).total_seconds())
Out[5]: '1 week'
```

Note how `format_timespan` does not access `timedelta` objects, unfortunately: only an integer (seconds).