# AttributeError when using "import dateutil" and "dateutil.parser.parse()" but no problems when using "from dateutil import parser"

Tags: python, python-2.7, attributeerror, python-dateutil

I was playing with the [`dateutil` module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) in Python 2.7.3. I simply wanted to use:

```
import dateutil
dateutil.parser.parse("01-02-2013")
```

But I got an error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parser'
```

I checked what attributes `dateutil` *does* have:

```
print dir(dateutil)
# output: ['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__',
#          '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__']
```

The thing is, when I try to import `parser` from `dateutil` directly, it does seem to exist:

```
from dateutil import parser
print parser.parse("01-02-2013")
# output: 2013-01-02 00:00:00
```

After the `from dateutil import parser`, `parser` has also magically appeared in the imported `dateutil` itself:

```
print dir(dateutil)
# output: ['__author__', '__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__license__',
#          '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__version__', 'parser',
#          'relativedelta', 'tz']
```

Note that some other attributes (like `rrule`) are still missing from this list.

Anyone knows what's going on?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You haven't imported `dateutil.parser`. You can see it, but you *have* to somehow import it.

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("01-02-2013")
datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 2, 0, 0)
```

That's because the `parser.py` is a module in the `dateutil` package. It's a separate file in the folder structure.

Answer to the question you asked in the comments, the reason why `relativedelta` and `tz` appear in the namespace after you've `from dateutil import parser` is because `parser` itself imports `relativedelta` and `tz`.

If you look at the source code of `dateutil/parser.py`, you can see the imports.

```
# -*- coding:iso-8859-1 -*-
"""
Copyright (c) 2003-2007  Gustavo Niemeyer <gustavo@niemeyer.net>

This module offers extensions to the standard Python
datetime module.
"""
... snip ...
from . import relativedelta
from . import tz
```

Comment: I thought you could just import it like you would import any other module. For example, if I wanted to use `datetime.date.today()`, I would first `import datetime`, and then `print datetime.date.today()`. Is there a reason this wouldn't work for `dateutil`?

Comment: I see. So all the other attributes in `dateutil` (like `rrule`) are separate files, and therefore you always have to use `import dateutil.[attribute_name]` to use them?

Comment: That's different, `date` is a class in the `datetime.py` file, where as `dateutil.parser` is actually a separate file, `parser.py` in the dateutil package.

Comment: @Neftas yes that's pretty much it.

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on why, after `from dateutil import parser`, the second `print dir(dateutil)` suddenly shows `relativedelta` and `tz`?

Comment: There we go, edited my answer to include an answer to the namespace question.