# How to not start the next day with datetime while adding a timedelta?

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Given a current time of `23:30:00` and I add two hours (7200 seconds). How can I get the time of the same day? So I want as a result `25:30:00`.

Currently I am only able to get the time of the next day:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> current_time  = "23:30:00"
>>> duration = 3600
>>> (datetime.strptime(current_time, "%H:%M:%S") + timedelta(seconds=duration)).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
'00:30:00'
```

Comment: Adding a `timedelta` to a `datetime` is time aware so adding two hours will automatically update the date if appropriate.   To get the behavior you want you'll  need to not use `datetime` objects.

Comment: Could you give an example on how to do that?

Comment: `25:30:00` is not a valid time.

Comment: I agree with you guys. I want to generate a valid GTFS dataset. Google defines that a trip that goes into the next day requires a time like this: https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#stop_times_fields

Comment: is the offset always hours?

Comment: No, it can also be minutes or seconds.

Comment: what should `duration = 36000` output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just wanting to increment hours minutes, seconds and create a string:

```
def weird_time(current_time,duration):
    start = datetime.strptime(current_time, "%H:%M:%S")
    st_hr, st_min, st_sec = start.hour, start.minute, start.second
    mn, secs = divmod(duration, 60)
    hour, mn = divmod(mn, 60)
    mn, secs = st_min+mn, st_sec+secs
    if secs > 59:
        m, secs = divmod(secs,60)
        mn += m
    if mn > 59:
        h, mn = divmod(mn,60)
        hour += h
    return "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(st_hr+hour, mn, secs)
```

Output:

```
In [19]: weird_time("23:30:00",7200)
Out[19]: '25:30:00'

In [20]: weird_time("23:30:00",3600)
Out[20]: '24:30:00'

In [21]: weird_time("23:30:59",7203)
Out[21]: '25:31:02'

In [22]: weird_time("23:30:59",3601)
Out[22]: '24:31:00'
```

Instead of doing all the calculations ourselves we can also use timedelta to calculate the total seconds and do our calculations from that:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta


def weird_time(current_time,duration):
    start = datetime.strptime(current_time, "%H:%M:%S")
    st_hr, st_min, st_sec = start.hour, start.minute, start.second
    comb = timedelta(minutes=st_min,seconds=st_sec) + timedelta(seconds=duration)
    mn, sec = divmod(comb.total_seconds(), 60)
    hour, mn = divmod(mn, 60)
    return "{:02}:{:02}:{:02}".format(int(st_hr+hour), int(mn), int(sec))
```

Which outputs the same:

```
In [29]: weird_time("23:30:00",7200)
Out[29]: '25:30:00'

In [30]: weird_time("23:30:00",3600)
Out[30]: '24:30:00'

In [31]: weird_time("23:30:59",7203)
Out[31]: '25:31:02'

In [32]: weird_time("23:30:59",3601)
Out[32]: '24:31:00'

In [33]:  weird_time("05:00:00",3600)
Out[33]: '06:00:00'
```

The hours just need to be incremented, the part that we need to catch is when either the combined total of either seconds, minutes or both is greater than 59.

Comment: I tried your code, it returned `33:30:00`. When desired output is `25:30:00`.

Comment: @sobolevn, that is because I set duration to 36000 originally, try it now

Comment: had a bug, ironed it out I think!

Comment: you don't need to implement the time arithmetics from scratch. [Use `timedelta` and format it at the end](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30477047/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I am using timedelta

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, **Instead of doing all the calculations ourselves we can also use timedelta to calculate the total seconds and do our calculations from that**, if you think your downvote is justified good for you, both parts to the answer are pretty easy to see and read.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like what you want is to just add two timedeltas to get another timedelta... right?

```
from datetime import timedelta as td

t0 = td(hours=23, minutes=30)
t1 = t0 + td(seconds=7200)
print(t1)  # prints "1 day, 1:30:00"
print("Hours: {}".format(t1.days*24 + int(t1.seconds/3600)))  # prints "Hours: 25"
```

Comment: upvote: for doing the time arithmetics using `timedelta`. My guess for the downvote: OP wants `"%H:%M:%S"` format e.g., `25:30:00` see [arrival_time](http://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#stop_times_fields)

Comment: // , Further reading on the `datetime.timedelta(days=0, seconds=0, microseconds=0, milliseconds=0, minutes=0, hours=0, weeks=0)` constructor: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects

Answer (score 2):

> I want to generate a valid GTFS dataset. Google defines that a trip that goes into the next day requires a time like this: http://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#stop_times_fields

To get the correct time you have to take into account daylight savings time changes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from tzlocal import get_localzone # $ pip install tzlocal

local_timezone = get_localzone()
current_time = datetime.now(local_timezone)
noon_naive = datetime.combine(current_time, time(12,0))
noon = local_timezone.localize(noon_naive, is_dst=None)

departure_time = (current_time - noon + timedelta(hours=12))
duration = timedelta(hours=2)
arrival_time = departure_time + duration
# -> datetime.timedelta(1, 5400)
```

To convert `timedelta` to `HH:MM:SS` format:

```
hours, seconds = divmod(arrival_time.total_seconds(), 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
print("%(hours)02d:%(minutes)02d:%(seconds)02d" % vars())
# -> 25:30:00
```

Comment: You can't import timezone from datetime.

Comment: @ustroetz: 1. You can in Python 3 2. It is not used in the code. I've removed it.