# How to format duration in Python (timedelta)?

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, duration, timedelta

I'm a newbie to python.
I was trying to display the time duration.
What I did was:

```
startTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
... <some more codes> ...
endTime = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
durationTime = endTime - startTime
print("The duration is " + str(durationTime))
```

The output is => The duration is 0:01:28
Can I know how to remove hour from the result?
I want to display => The duration is 01:28

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like you have to do it yourself, as suggested [in this post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906926/formatting-python-timedelta-objects

Comment: Would `strftime()` not work here?

Comment: `durationTime` is a `datetime.timedelta` object. `strftime` is not applicable on `datetime.timedelta` objects.

Comment: Thanks everyone for help! ^^

Comment: you probably want to [use `timeit` module here instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can do this by converting `durationTime` which is a `datetime.timedelta` object to a `datetime.time` object and then using `strftime`.

```
print datetime.time(0, 0, durationTime.seconds).strftime("%M:%S")
```

Another way would be to manipulate the string:

```
print ':'.join(str(durationTime).split(':')[1:])
```

Comment: Thanks! The first method solved my problem. :)

Comment: which will work only if you have a duration of less than 60 seconds (((((((((((

Answer (score 11):

You can split your timedelta as follows:

```
>>> hours, remainder = divmod(durationTime.total_seconds(), 3600)
>>> minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
>>> print '%s:%s' % (minutes, seconds)
```

This will use python's builtin divmod to convert the number of seconds in your timedelta to hours, and the remainder will then be used to calculate the minutes and seconds. You can then explicitly print the units of time you want.

Comment: `print(f"{minutes}:{seconds:02}")` would look a bit better, I think.