# How Do I Format a pandas timedelta object?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am using *pandas* `timedelta` objects to keep track of split times in a sports related data set using the following sort of construction:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_timedelta("-0:0:1.0")
```

This natively reports as:

`-1 days +23:59:59`

I can get the raw seconds count using `pd.to_timedelta("-0:0:1.0").total_seconds()` but that is unwieldy where the negative amount is in minutes or hours:

For the expression:

```
pd.to_timedelta("-1:2:3.0")
```

how can I get the report formatted as`"-1:2:3.0`, or `-1 hour, 2 minutes, 3 seconds`, from the `timedelta` object, rather than in the form `-3723.0000000000005` (with a float error) or `-1 days +22:57:57`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the function `strfdelta(tdelta, fmt)` provided as an answer to a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907269/454773

Comment: Any idea how to apply this formatting to whole column while printing out `df.to_html()` ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sad solution that works (but not for `mydelta > 23:47:16.854775807`).

```py
(pd.to_datetime('2262-04-11') + mydelta).strftime('%H:%M')
```

#### Update

This works for larger `mydelta` but requires manual formatting.

```py
y = mydelta.total_seconds()
h = 3600
tstr = f'{int(y/h)}:{int(y%h/60):02d}:{int(y%60):02d}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?

```
In [223]: df
Out[223]:
              delta
0 -1 days +23:59:59
1 -1 days +22:57:57
2          00:00:11

In [224]: df.delta.abs().dt.components
Out[224]:
   days  hours  minutes  seconds  milliseconds  microseconds  nanoseconds
0     0      0        0        1             0             0            0
1     0      1        2        3             0             0            0
2     0      0        0       11             0             0            0
```

Comment: Doh! Okay, yes.. if negative take the absolute. The components method is handy too...

What I was really looking for was a way of controlling the display format of the the delta object directly using something like `strftime` formatting.