# Formating "posted x seconds ago" in Jinja 2(Flask) with strftime?

Tags: python, flask

I'd like to make my code a little more user-friendly such that when users post something, i'd like it to say "x seconds/hour/day ago"

so far my code is

```
{{ post.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You want [`datetime.timedelta()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects)

```
import datetime
import time

old_time = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(20)
new_time = datetime.datetime.now()

# The below line returns a 'timedelta' object.
delta = new_time - old_time

print('{} seconds have passed.'.format(delta.total_seconds()))

# or
print(
    '{} days, {} hours, {} minutes, {} seconds passed.'.format(
        delta.days,
        delta.seconds//3600,
        (delta.seconds//60)%60,
        int(delta.total_seconds()%60)))
```

I believe it also exists for just `date` and `time` modules as well.

Comment: While this works, it is typically not very nice to format the passed time in seconds only. To get minutes and hours, a custom filter is needed, to check and transform the `timedela` object to a nice looking string.

Comment: Added that, too.

Comment: I think it's worth checking out the rather elegant solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906926/formatting-python-timedelta-objects) for a very `strftime`-like option.