# Remove the days in the timedelta object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a column in a pandas `dataframe` that is created after subtracting two times. I now have a `timedelta` object like this `-1 days +02:45:00`. I just need to remove the -1 days and want it to be `02:45:00`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907269/2570277) answers your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can subtract [`days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.days.html) converted to timedeltas:

```
td = pd.to_timedelta(['-1 days +02:45:00','1 days +02:45:00','0 days +02:45:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'td': td})

df['td'] = df['td'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['td'].dt.days, unit='d')

print (df.head())

        td
0 02:45:00
1 02:45:00
2 02:45:00

print (type(df.loc[0, 'td']))
<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'>
```

Or convert timedeltas to strings and extract strings between `days` and `.`:

```
df['td'] = df['td'].astype(str).str.extract('days (.*?)\.')
print (df.head())
          td
0  +02:45:00
1   02:45:00
2   02:45:00

print (type(df.loc[0, 'td']))
<class 'str'>
```

Comment: The only one of the 2 solutions provided that worked was the string manipulation. The timedelta difference still shows `0 days ` and then the time difference

Answer (score 2):

I found this method easy, others didnt work for me

```py
df['column'] = df['column'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x[7:])
```

It slices of the days part and you only get time part

Answer (score 0):

If your column is named time1, you can do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df['time1'] = pd.to_datetime(str(df.time1)[11:19]) #this slice can be adjusted
df['time1'] = df.time1.dt.time
```

this is going to convert the timedelta to str, slice the time part from it, convert it to datetime and extract the time from that.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very easy solution for other people who may encounter this problem:

```
if timedelta_obj.days < 0:
    timedelta_obj.days = datetime.timedelta(
        seconds=timedelta_obj.total_seconds() + 3600*24)
```