# Python Pandas: Removing 0 days suffix from time column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that contains column time. The data type of time column is `timedelta64[ns]`. The time column contains 0 days as a suffix. The time column looks like as follow:

```
df['time']:

0 days 00:00:00
0 days 00:30:00
0 days 01:00:00
0 days 01:30:00
0 days 02:00:00
```

I am trying to remove the 0 days from the column by following the existing thread ([Remove the days in the timedelta object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129971/remove-the-days-in-the-timedelta-object)). However, it did not remove 0 days from the column. Could anyone guide me on how to get rid of 0 days from the timedelta64 datatype column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [timedelta to string type in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101432/timedelta-to-string-type-in-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
df['time'] = pd.Series([pd.Timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(0,100,5)])
df['time'] = df['time'].astype(str).str.split('0 days ').str[-1]
df
```

Output:

```
        time
0   00:00:00
1   00:05:00
2   00:10:00
3   00:15:00
4   00:20:00
5   00:25:00
6   00:30:00
7   00:35:00
8   00:40:00
9   00:45:00
10  00:50:00
11  00:55:00
12  01:00:00
13  01:05:00
14  01:10:00
15  01:15:00
16  01:20:00
17  01:25:00
18  01:30:00
19  01:35:00
```