# Subtracting 2 columns of date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I'm using python with pandas and datetime.

I have dataframe in csv file like that:

[image]

I too add new column called "Duration" by subtracting "Start date" from "End date".

what I have tried to do:

```
rides['Duration'] = end_time - start_time
duration = rides['Duration']

print(rides['Duration'])
```

and what I get is:

```
0     0 days 00:03:01
1     0 days 02:07:02
2     0 days 00:05:43
```

what I want to get is:

```
0     00:03:01
1     02:07:02
2     00:05:43
```

That is, I want to remove the "days" and show only the time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove the days in the timedelta object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129971/remove-the-days-in-the-timedelta-object).

Answer (score 0):

You can use % format specifier to extract hour, minute and second.

```
print("%d:%d:%d"%(rides['Duration'].hour,rides['Duration'].minute,rides['Duration'].second))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try via `rsplit()` if you want 'Duration' column of type `object`:

```
rides['Duration']=rides['Duration'].astype(str).str.rsplit(' ',1).str[1].str.strip('+|-')
```

**OR**

Try via `rsplit()` and `to_datetime()` if you want 'Duration' column of type  `datetime.time`:

```
rides['Duration']=pd.to_datetime(rides['Duration'].astype(str).str.rsplit(' ',1).str[1].str.strip('+|-')).dt.time
```

Comment: Thank you, your first method worked fine. but now I have another problem. The dtype is object and I need it to be "timedelta64[ns]". How can I handle it?

Comment: then use the second method as it will create `datetime.time`

Comment: I've tried the second method, I get this error: "ParserError: Unknown string format: +23:04:14"

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and help and sorry if I ask too many questions and bother you but the dtype is still "object" :(

Comment: No.....If you used second method then it's of type `datetime.time` and you can cross verify by `rides['Duration'].map(type)`