# ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence when trying to pull index of max value in columns

Tags: python, pandas, argmax

Try to get the index of the max value in column **Hi** column so I can get the value in the **Time** column

NumPy/pandas is up to date

The output of the panda's data frame:

```
        Date      Time     Hi       Lo      Open   Close    Volume
241 2021-12-10   9:28  175.190  175.100  175.120  175.15    10780
242 2021-12-10   9:29  175.270  175.150  175.150  175.23    12863
243 2021-12-10   9:30  176.030  175.140  175.250  175.71  1370478
244 2021-12-10   9:31  175.900  175.460  175.710  175.90   435577
245 2021-12-10   9:32  176.100  175.680  175.880  175.73   485381
246 2021-12-10   9:33  175.870  175.370  175.740  175.62   450575
247 2021-12-10   9:34  176.100  175.520  175.609  176.05   485467
248 2021-12-10   9:35  176.110  175.540  176.060  175.64   484336
249 2021-12-10   9:36  176.150  175.510  175.650  176.01   462430
250 2021-12-10   9:37  176.320  175.870  175.992  176.17   502685
251 2021-12-10   9:38  176.530  176.140  176.165  176.47   668669
252 2021-12-10   9:39  176.556  176.345  176.480  176.37   577773
253 2021-12-10   9:40  176.420  176.005  176.350  176.01   388618
254 2021-12-10   9:41  176.050  175.660  176.010  176.01   511461
255 2021-12-10   9:42  176.030  175.810  176.011  175.89   277475
256 2021-12-10   9:43  176.215  175.880  175.908  176.19   315341
257 2021-12-10   9:44  176.450  176.010  176.180  176.03   426582
258 2021-12-10   9:45  176.360  175.880  176.020  175.94   513756
259 2021-12-10   9:46  176.030  175.760  175.940  175.80   367906
260 2021-12-10   9:47  175.775  175.450  175.775  175.56   481068
261 2021-12-10   9:48  175.760  175.450  175.550  175.74   369607
262 2021-12-10   9:49  175.890  175.560  175.730  175.66   290529
263 2021-12-10   9:50  175.860  175.550  175.660  175.83   310516
264 2021-12-10   9:51  176.120  175.810  175.840  176.01   428011
265 2021-12-10   9:52  176.060  175.721  176.015  175.83   275272
266 2021-12-10   9:53  176.010  175.745  175.830  175.78   291982
267 2021-12-10   9:54  175.895  175.670  175.790  175.70   188332
268 2021-12-10   9:55  175.705  175.240  175.685  175.38   448620
269 2021-12-10   9:56  175.380  175.050  175.380  175.16   430128
270 2021-12-10   9:57  175.400  174.925  175.150  174.93   453117
271 2021-12-10   9:58  175.001  174.690  174.920  174.78   422128
272 2021-12-10   9:59  175.210  174.750  174.775  175.18   380997
273 2021-12-10  10:00  175.510  175.090  175.180  175.45   361698
274 2021-12-10  10:01  175.630  175.360  175.455  175.42   260332
```

Code I'm working with currently below:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy

Symbol = "AAPL"

with open(Symbol +'.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    df = pd.DataFrame(csv_reader, columns=['Date','Hi', 'Lo','Open','Close','Volume'])

    #df.set_index('Volume', inplace=True)

    new_df_no_expand = df['Date'].str.split(' ') #splitting the date form the time and adding the time to a new column
    New_df = df['Date'].str.split(' ', expand=True).rename(columns={0:'Date',1:'Time'}) #splitting the date form the time and adding the time to a new column needs tweaking

    df[['Date', 'Time']] = df['Date'].str.split(' ', n=1, expand=True)
   
    df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Hi', 'Lo','Open','Close','Volume'])

    df['Open'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Open'])
    df['Hi'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Hi'])
    df['Lo'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Lo'])
    df['Close'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Close'])
    df['Volume'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Volume'])

    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

    hodtime = df.loc[df[(df['Time'] >= "9:30") & (df['Time'] <= "10:00")]['Hi'].idxmax()]

    print(hodtime)
```

When I run this it gives me this output:

```
ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence
```

My desired output: (Max value in hi column is at index 252)

```
High of Day Time is 9:39
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146 and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Where does the error occur? Why do you think it occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're a using `split` to create columns `Date` and `Time`, then, you convert the `Date` column using `to_datetime`, but `Time` column is still of **object** type. You need to convert the `Time` column to [`timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) to be able to execute the comparison.

```py
...
...
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],infer_datetime_format=True)

df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time+":00")

lower_time = pd.to_timedelta("9:30:00")
higher_time = pd.to_timedelta("10:00:00")

hodtime = df.loc[df[(df['Time'] >= lower_time) & (df['Time'] <= higher_time)]['Hi'].idxmax()]
print(hodtime)
```

```
Date           2021-12-10
Time      0 days 09:39:00
Hi                176.556
Lo                176.345
Open               176.48
Close              176.37
Volume             577773
Name: 252, dtype: object
```

Comment: Perfect, any way to remove the "0 days" part of the time? @n1colas.m

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53130019/13144143) answer does exactly what you want. @Cash.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect your problem is in the part that subsets on a time interval; it likely returns an empty data structure which is what this error is telling you.  The idxmax() cannot find the argmax of a series with nothing in it.

The part below is probably the issue.  What does this look like if you print it?   What is the data type of the 'Time' column?

```
df[(df['Time'] >= "9:30") & (df['Time'] <= "10:00")]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: There was no question asked.