# Remove the days in Timedelta column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

This is a column in my data frame and I want to remove the 0 days so the column will just show the time

```
           Time
0     0 days 04:00:00
1     0 days 04:01:00
2     0 days 04:03:00
3     0 days 04:04:00
4     0 days 04:07:00
```

Desired output:

```
         Time
0      04:00:00
1      04:01:00
2      04:03:00
3      04:04:00
4      04:07:00
```

I've been recommended this question > [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53129971/remove-the-days-in-the-timedelta-object/53130019#53130019)

And tried to suit it to my code with this code:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].dt.days, unit='d')
```

But I'm still getting the same output:

```
           Time
0     0 days 04:00:00
1     0 days 04:01:00
2     0 days 04:03:00
3     0 days 04:04:00
4     0 days 04:07:00
```

Comment: If you want a custom string representation of timedelta, you'll have to [format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/10197418) by yourself. There's no such thing as `strftime` as you have it for formatting datetime to string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about the time-intelligence of `dtype: timedelta64[ns]` you can cast it to string and remove the '0 days ' part:

```
df.Time.astype(str).str.replace('0 days ', '')
```

##### Update

In case the Time column is not always '0 days', you can remove the days with the following code:

```
df['Time'] = df['Time'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].dt.days, unit='d')
```

Comment: What if the days attribute is not zero?

Comment: Since it is a time column, I assume it is always 0. However, if this is not the case:`df['Time'] = df['Time'] - pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'].dt.days, unit='d')`

Comment: With the data I'm collecting it will always be zero. @
MrFuppes

Comment: Then to represent time, OP should use datetime data type, not timedelta

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
df['Time'].astype(str).str.split(' ').str[-1]
Out[288]: 
0    04:00:00
1    04:01:00
2    04:03:00
3    04:07:00
Name: Time, dtype: object
```