# How to convert seconds to a custom interval format in a dynamic Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

## tl; dr

Is it possible to convert all float values in this DataFrame pivot table from seconds to intervals in the `HH:MM:SS` format?

```
Name        Student A  Tutor
Date
2021-04-12       52.0   86.0
2021-04-13       13.0  113.0
2021-04-14        NaN   34.0
Average          32.5   77.6
```

Desired end result:

```
Name         Student A         Tutor
Date
2021-04-12    00:00:52      00:01:26
2021-04-13    00:00:13      00:01:53
2021-04-14                  00:00:34
Average       00:00:32      00:01:17
```

Caveats:

- *Tutor* and *Student A* columns are dynamic so I cannot reference them by names. In fact, there might be multiple students in the table.
- I have had no luck with applying `pd.to_timedelta` as it prefixes everything with "0 days".
- The table also has the total column and row but I've removed it for clarity.

---

## Long read

This is how the pivot table has been built:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': ['2021-04-12', '2021-04-12', '2021-04-13', '2021-04-13', '2021-04-14'],
    'Name': ['Tutor', 'Student A', 'Student A', 'Tutor', 'Tutor'],
    'duration_seconds': [86, 52, 13, 113, 34]
})
```

`df` looks like this:

```
         Date       Name  duration_seconds
0  2021-04-12      Tutor                86
1  2021-04-12  Student A                52
2  2021-04-13  Student A                13
3  2021-04-13      Tutor               113
4  2021-04-14      Tutor                34
```

Grouping it

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Name', 'Date']).sum()
```

yields:

```
                       duration_seconds
Name        Date
Student A   2021-04-12               52
            2021-04-13               13
Tutor       2021-04-12               86
            2021-04-13              113
            2021-04-14               34
```

Converting data to the desired format

```
pivoted = grouped.pivot_table(
    values='duration_seconds',
    index='Date',
    columns='Name'
)
```

yields:

```
Name        Student A  Tutor
Date
2021-04-12       52.0   86.0
2021-04-13       13.0  113.0
2021-04-14        NaN   34.0
```

Adding the averages row

```
pivoted.loc['Average'] = pivoted.mean()
```

yields:

```
Name        Student A       Tutor
Date
2021-04-12       52.0   86.000000
2021-04-13       13.0  113.000000
2021-04-14        NaN   34.000000
Average          32.5   77.666667
```

This is how far I've got with this. The last step would be to convert all values under the student and tutor columns to intervals in the `HH:MM:SS` format.

This would be a good way to achieve it had it not been prefixing everything with `0 days` :

```
pivoted.iloc[:].apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='s')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def strfdelta(tdelta, fmt):
    d = {"days": tdelta.days}
    d["hours"], rem = divmod(tdelta.seconds, 3600)
    d["minutes"], d["seconds"] = divmod(rem, 60)
    return fmt.format(**d)


df = df.apply(
    lambda x: [
        strfdelta(
            pd.Timedelta(seconds=v),
            "{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}",
        )
        if pd.notna(v)
        else ""
        for v in x
    ],
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
           Student A     Tutor
2021-04-12  00:00:52  00:01:26
2021-04-13  00:00:13  00:01:53
2021-04-14            00:00:34
Average     00:00:32  00:01:17
```

The `strfdelta` function is from [Formatting timedelta objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906926/formatting-timedelta-objects/8907269#8907269)