# Problem adding difference of two timestamps in txt file in python

Tags: python

I have the following error when i try to add the difference of two timestamps in txt file in python

```
TimeStamp3 = TimeStamp2 - TimeStamp1
TimeStamp3_str = TimeStamp_3.strftime("%d (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
LogFile.write('Total time: ' + TimeStamp3_Str + '\n')


AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime
```

Comment: Googling your error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906926/formatting-timedelta-objects

Comment: what is the type of TimeStamp2

Comment: can you share the traceback?

Comment: TimeStamp2 = datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: TimeStamp1 = datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: i only want to write the duration in txt file 
the print(TimeStamp3)  works file but i cannot parse it into file

Comment: i used TimeStamp4 = str(TimeStamp3) and works fine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)