# Python 3 - How to change the syntax of a "datetime.timedelta(seconds=xxx)" object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, timedelta

below a simple example using the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> 
>>> time=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
>>> str(time)
'0:00:10'
>>>
```

how can I change the syntaxt of the **time** object when I convert it in a string? As reslt, I want to see **'00:00:10'** and not **'0:00:10'**. I really don't understand why the last zero in the hours block is missing, I want to see always two digits in each block. how can I do it?

Comment: Why are you using a `timedelta` instead of an actual `datetime.time` or `datetime.datetime`? The latter can be formatted with `datetime.strftime` (or with normal format strings or f-strings) that gives you full control, just read the `datetime` docs.

Comment: so how con I convert seconds to hours, minutes and seconds without using "timedelta"? what is the right syntaxt? then I need to take the string in this format '%H:%M:%S'.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: `datetime.timedelta` is the right type to express "10 seconds". `datetime.time` would be the right type to express something like "12:00:10 AM", but it doesn't sound like that's the goal here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create your custom formatter to do this.

Python3 variant of @gumption solution which is written in python2.
[This is the link to his solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30536361/12906648)

**Custom Formatter**

```py
from string import Template

class TimeDeltaTemp(Template):
    delimiter = "%"

def strfdtime(dtime, formats):
    day = {"D": dtime.days}
    hours, rem = divmod(dtime.seconds, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(rem, 60)
    day["H"] = '{:02d}'.format(hours)
    day["M"] = '{:02d}'.format(minutes)
    day["S"] = '{:02d}'.format(seconds)
    time = TimeDeltaTemp(formats.upper())
    return time.substitute(**day)
```

**Usage**

```py
import datetime

time=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10)
print(strfdtime(time, '%H:%M:%S'))
time=datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
print(strfdtime(time, '%h:%m:%s'))
```

**Output**

```
00:00:10
00:00:30
```

Comment: cool, but is it the only way to reach my goal? I mean, must I really create a custom class and function?

Comment: I'm sure there's another way but I think this will be more cleaner.

Comment: Your solution fixes another point. **time=datetime.timedelta(seconds=10000000)** for example, covenrted in a string, is **115 days, 17:46:40** but your code get always the '%h:%m:%s' output with the hour block fixed, and it was exactly what I wanted to see. good job!