# Convert timedelta "9:50:00" to String "09:50"

Tags: python, time, type-conversion

How can you convert the timedelta so that it only outputs "09:50" as a string instead of output: "9:50:00"?

```
from datetime import timedelta

y = 3
x = 30

time1 = timedelta(hours=6, minutes=20)
time2 = timedelta(hours=y, minutes=x)

future = time1 + time2

print(future)

future_str = str(future)

print(future_str)
```

Comment: Possible duplicates: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906926/formatting-timedelta-objects

Answer (score 1):

Code that works is:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
y = 3
x = 30
time1 = timedelta(hours=6, minutes=20)
time2 = timedelta(hours=y, minutes=x)
future = time1 + time2
s = (datetime(1, 1, 1) + future).strftime("%H:%M")
print(s)
>>> 09:50
```

Explanation: timedelta doesn't have strftime() method, that's why other answers are failing, so we need to convert it back to datetime, an easy trick is to add a dummy datetime object

Comment: Hi Svfat, thank you its works! one more please i am a beginner could you explain to me what you did ? What makes date time(1,1,1) ?

Comment: datetime(1,1,1) is just a "dummy" datetime object, this of this like of a beginning of the timeline (year zero)
when we adding timedelta object to it, we are getting another datetime object, which has strftime method to convert it to the proper format

so it is like 00:00 + 09:50

Answer (score 0):

If you already have string **"9:50:00"** you can just slice it.

`future_str = "9:50:00"[0:4]`

Comment: that's not a general solution, what about "10:50:00"?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
'{:0>8}'.format(future_str)[:5])
```

Answer (score -1):

use `strftime("%H:%M")`
which helps to format your time example code below

`future_str = future.strftime("%H:%M")`

It return => 09:50

Comment: Did you try it? it raise an exception.

Comment: No it doesn't, it raises `AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Comment: sorry you should import datetime

Comment: The OP already import `datetime`, and importing something doesn't add functionality to another library.

Comment: Seems it's ChatGPT generated answer...