# Python: How to get difference of 2 dates in HH:MM format?

Tags: python, date, time, subtraction

I have 2 datetime objects:

```
a 
datetime.datetime(2013,2,11,15,35)

b
datetime.datetime(2013,2,11,18,55)
```

The difference is 3:20

How can I obtain this in python?

I do:

```
(b-a).seconds/3600
```

But I get 3 instead of 3:20

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python format timedelta to string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is manual construction acceptable? If you subtract the two datetimes you'll get a timedelta object. Then just grab the values from that:

```
>>> diff = b - a
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 12000)

>>> hrs = diff.seconds / 3600
>>> hrs
3
>>> mins = diff.seconds % 3600 / 60
>>> mins
20
>>> "%s:%s" % (hrs, mins)
'3:20'
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you also show how I add timedelta objects? for example I get the difference of date_a and date_b, then the difference of date_c and date_d, then I want to sum the differences.

Comment: @alwbtc  Adding is with `+`: `(date_b - date_a) + (date_d - date_c)`.

Comment: Could you also show how to create a timedelta object which is 00:00? it means 0 hours and 0 minutes. I will add timedeltas to this object.

Comment: @alwbtc `my_td = datetime.timedelta()`

Comment: @alwbtc Don't forget to select your accepted answer from the three provided! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> diff = b - a
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(0, 12000)
>>> (datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) + diff).strftime("%H:%M")
'03:20'
```

could be also a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

maybe i think the hours is :

```
(b-a).days*24 +(b-a).seconds/3600
```

here it is another way:

```
x = (b-a).seconds/3600.0 + (b-a).days*24
hours = int(x)
mins = int((x - hours)*60)
```