# Is there a method to generate a string that represents a relative time measurement?

Tags: python, time

I want a script to produce a readable output that shows how long ago a file was modified. It's quite easy to use Python to obtain the time the file was last modified:

```
print time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(sys.argv[1]))
```

This prints out "Sun Jun 16 05:03:37 2013" which is quite nice.

However what I want to print is "4 hours, 3 minutes", and if I run that 3 minutes after that, it will say "4 hours, 6 minutes". etc.

So I can obtain a delta in seconds by subtracting `os.path.getmtime(filename)` from `time.time()`. It looks like I can use `datetime`'s `timedelta` somehow to do this easily, but the documentation goes into quite a bit of detail and I haven't found a straightforward example yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found another topic here:

[Python format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/340947)

Looks like there is a limitation of about a hundred million seconds, so I guess I need to handle it differently if the difference is greater than that.

Comment: I think [Adam Jacob Muller's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13756038/1405065) on that question will do exactly what you want.