# How to change timedelta into time duration in Python?

Tags: python, time

I have a timedelta time like this:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 175, 941041)
```

I want to convert this into duration. For example:

```
1 second 
2-59 seconds
1 minute
2minutes-59minutes
1 hour
1 hour 50 minutes
2 hours
1 day 5 hours 45 minutes
```

How can I do this in Python?

First, I tried to converting timedelta into seconds like this and later convert into duration:

```
def timedelta_to_seconds(td):
    return td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400)
```

But I get this error while running this function:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'microseconds'
```

Comment: would this perhaps be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string

Comment: @AMADANONInc., write your comment instead as an answer, it seems the most appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(0, 175, 941041))
'0:02:55.941041'
```

Now you can get the Hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds.

OR

Refer to [this post if you want nice readable timedelta](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498062-nicely-readable-timedelta/)

Answer (score 1):

Ithink what you are passing to this function is not a timedelta, and that's why it has no attribute microseconds.

I have this from time to time, when I call a function to get the timedelta as

```
a=get_my_timedelta
```

instead of

```
a=get_my_timedelta()
```