# Output of Time difference is not as is expected

Tags: python, django-models, django-forms

models.py:

```
class Attendancename(models.Model):
    teacher_name = models.ForeignKey(Teachername)
    date = models.DateField('Date')
    intime = models.TimeField('IN-TIME')
    outtime = models.TimeField('OUT-TIME')
    def hours_conversion(self):
        tdelta = (datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),self.outtime) - datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(),self.intime))
        res = float((tdelta).seconds/3600)
        return '{0:.2f}'.format(res,)
```

I used to define method inside my models class to calculate the time difference between `'intime'` and `'outtime'`. I also got succeed in it, but the results are not as I expect.

I have entered `'intime'`-09:00 am and `'outime'`-12:32 pm in my form field and it shows me `'total hours'` - 3.54hr as output.

Can any body have any idea what's going wrong exactly?
Thanks! in advance.

Comment: I don't see an issue. That is 3.54 hours, not 3 hours and 54 minutes.

Comment: And `60 * 0.54` is roughly `32`.

Comment: So how can I show it in a format as - 3hr 32min?

Comment: `return '{0}:{1}'.format(tdelta.hours, tdelta.minutes)`

Comment: Or alternatively: `return '{t.hours}:{t.minutes}'.format(t=tdelta)`

Comment: but it throws error "datetime.delta has no attribute: 'hours'"...

Comment: related: [Python format timedelta to string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your output in the form of `hh:mm` (3:32), you need to access those attributes of the timedelta. Replace your return statement with the following.

```
hours, minutes = tdelta.seconds//3600, (tdelta.seconds//60)%60
return '{0}:{1}'.format(hours, minutes)
```

Answer (score 0):

output is the amount of hours to get in form of hours and minute

```
output = '{0:.2f}'.format(res,)
hours = output-(output%1)
minutes = (output%1)*60
return hours+":"+minutes
```

would be required

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind seconds; you could just call `str()` function:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> td = timedelta(hours=3, minutes=32)
>>> str(td)
'3:32:00'
```

You could drop seconds and microseconds:

```
>>> str(td).rpartition(':')[0]
'3:32'
```

Or you could format manually:

```
hours, seconds = divmod(td.total_seconds(), 3600)
minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
print("%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes))
# -> 03:32
```