# Date Formatting Pandas - Python

Tags: javascript, python, pandas

I am using pandas in python and I end up with the following table:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
|        start        |        finish        |    duration     |
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+
| 2013-08-12 12:00:00 | 2013-08-14 16:00:00 | 2 days 04:00:00 |
+---------------------+----------------------+-----------------+

dataframe=dataframe.to_json(orient='records',date_format='iso',double_precision=2,date_unit='s')

return jsonify(data=dataframe)
```

I send this over using an AJAX request as `data`, and on the javascript side I end up with `data.duration = 1970-01-03T04:00:00Z`

How can I format the data frame so that when I call `data.duration` I get `2 days 04:00:00`?

Note that duration is calculating using:

```
data_frame['duration'] = data_frame['finish'] - data_frame['start']
```

Comment: Maybe convert duration to a string with str() for reading in javascript, the simple approach and reached as a concensus some years ago on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the duration column uses a type that is not strictly available in Javascript.

Try casting the duration column to String in Python or explicitly replacing the column or creating a new column of formatted strings.  I would suspect the current `dtype` of that column in the pandas dataframe is a Python timedelta or similar.

After serialization to JSON and transport it looks like duration was interpreted as a JavaScript `Date` because 2 days and 4 hours has been transformed to 2 days and 4 hours after the epoch date of Jan 1, 1970, the "zero" of [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) that is also the JS time standard.  In Javascript `Date` objects are similar to `DateTime` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit ugly, but you can cast to the `pandas` string representation like this:

```
dataframe['duration'].apply(lambda x: str(pd.Timedelta(x)))
```