# how to subtract only the time of datetime objects in python

Tags: python, datetime

I want to subtract the time between 2 column: I have been using this:

```
row['window'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Time'], '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime.strptime(row['announcement_time'], '%H:%M:%S')
```

This works and gives a result that look like this:

```
 window
-1 day, 23:29:00
-1 day, 23:29:05
-1 day, 23:29:10
-1 day, 23:29:15
-1 day, 23:29:20
-1 day, 23:29:25
```

However, I only want the time difference i.e. - 00:00:30. I have tried :

```
 row['window'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Time'], '%H:%M:%S.%f').time() - datetime.datetime.strptime(row['announcement_time'], '%H:%M:%S').time()
```

But this gives an error :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

I have also tried .hour, .minute and .second but does not work very well.
Can someone please help.Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to calculate the difference before formating it? I would try sth like datetime.datetime.strptime(row['time'] - row['announcement_time'], '%H:%M:%S')

Comment: Could you post some of the actual input data as well?

Comment: Maybe you want to store only seconds: `(datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Time'], '%H:%M:%S.%f') - datetime.datetime.strptime(row['announcement_time'], '%H:%M:%S')).total_seconds()`

Comment: @fuuman: I tried that but they are in different formats so I need to convert to datetime object

Comment: @acdr: the row['Time[L]) has this format HH:MM:SS.000 eg: 14:20:04.000 and the row['announcement_time'] has HH:MM:SS format eg: 15:44:22T

Answer (score 0):

Time objects don't have arithmetic that I'm aware of. For best practice you should use `(datetime.datetime object - datetime.datetime object).days` for example.

[You can read more about it here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html).

Answer (score 0):

`-1 day, 23:29:25` is how negative `timedelta`s are printed. To get `00:00:30`, use `abs()`:

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> -timedelta(seconds=30)
datetime.timedelta(-1, 86370)
>>> str(-timedelta(seconds=30))
'-1 day, 23:59:30'
>>> str(abs(-timedelta(seconds=30)))
'0:00:30'
```

If `timedelta()` is more than a day, you could apply modulo arithmetic, to get  the time difference within a day:

```
>>> str(abs(-timedelta(days=10, seconds=30)))
'10 days, 0:00:30'
>>> str(abs(-timedelta(days=10, seconds=30)) % timedelta(days=1))
'0:00:30'
```

On Python 2, `% timedelta()` is not implemented. You could use `.total_seconds() % 3600` instead or if you need only the whole number of seconds then just access `.seconds` attribute (it is always less than a day):

```
>>> abs(-timedelta(days=10, seconds=30)).seconds
30
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. However, I would like to get the -30 second or -10:20 (negative 10 minutes and 20 secs). or is there away to reformat "-1 day, 23:29:05"?

Comment: @duckman  yes. If you don't need to change the value and you want only to format it differently then it is a [separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/4279). In your case, you could add at the end: `if diff < timedelta(0): result = '-' + result`