# Python datetime over one day

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.datetime.now()

end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print (end_time - start_time)
```

I try to to use `datetime` to get the execution time.

If it took almost 11 hours, it will show like `11:07:13.215032`

If more than 24 hours, how to show the time?

e.g. 35 hours 11minutes 37 seconds

```
1) 35:11:37
2) 1:11:11:37
```

Which one will be shown?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself by assigning a "fake" date to `start_time`?

Comment: It will show 2 since it went to days.

Comment: Why don't you try? datetime can receive some arguments, check the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html Remember to select the version of Python you are using in the upper corner, or tell me your version and ill provide you the way to check it by yourself

Comment: Even simpler test: `from datetime import timedelta; print timedelta(days=2, hours=4)`

Comment: You're trying to pring a `timedelta`-object, this answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/539360/2756793

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just give it a `start_time`

```
import datetime
start_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('1997-01-01 00:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
end_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print (end_time - start_time)
```

Output:

```
7363 days, 17:06:57.965556
```