# How do you override the way django displays DurationField as string?

Tags: django

In my form I am expecting the user to enter a two part time...`HH:mm` but when the update form is loaded the duration field value is returned as `HH:mm:ss`

So when saving a value:

```
duration: 13:00
```

When editing the form the initial data will be:

```
duration 13:00:00
```

When saving that I get an `ValidationError` as that is not a format I want to accept.

```
            if ':' in duration:
                try:
                    (hours, minutes,) = duration.split(':')
                except ValueError:
                    self.add_error(
                        'duration',
                        _("Invalid duration: {}".format(duration))
                    )
                    return duration
```

Is there a way to only show the `HH:mm` format for all places I am showing the `DurationField` or is it better to just set it in the initial data of the form?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a `DurationField` why do you add validation? The validation provided by Django should work and will accept '13:00' as input as well as '13:00:00'. Just add a placeholder text like '13:00' to your widget so your user knows what to enter but don't add obstacles by forbidding '13:00:00'.

If you're using a `ModelForm`, in the `Meta` class:

```
widgets = {'duration': TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '13:00'})}
```

Internally, your duration is saved as `datetime.timedelta` so you should just validate on valid durations you want to accept (like no more than 12 hours...). And whereever you need to output the `duration`, you can format it as you wish (e.g. see [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/python-format-timedelta-to-string) on the subject).

To override how the value is displayed in your input field, you should subclass `forms.DurationField`:

```
from django.utils.duration import _get_duration_components

def hhmm_duration_string(duration):
    days, hours, minutes, seconds, microseconds = 
       _get_duration_components(duration)

    string = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(hours, minutes)
    return string

class HHMMDurationField(forms.DurationField):
    def prepare_value(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, datetime.timedelta):
            return hhmm_duration_string(value)
        return value
```

Comment: The requirement was entering time as a decimal and a time field. Also min and max value validators don't work on `DurationFields` so have had to make a few concessions although using the out the box field is always my preference

Comment: You can always validate min, max in your form using the `clean_duration()` method, so I don't see the problem with validation. Also since your HTML input field is a text input field, it would be nice to your users to give them flexibility of input (while telling them as an example that 13:00 is the expected input). Better yet, if you really want to make it easy, is to let them enter hours and minutes in two separate input fields (subclass `MultiValueField` for the field and `MultiWidget` for the widget).

Comment: I like your answer, keep it standard. It is now about convincing the client to not enter time in the `5.5` decimal format.