# Converting ints to timedelta with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have some values in a pandas df that are positive and negative ints, and I want to convert them to timedeltas so I can put them into a DurationField in a Django model.

```
             date  dep_time dep_delay  arr_time arr_delay cancelled carrier  \
103992 2014-05-11  10:13:00        -2  12:47:00       -13         0      B6   
103993 2014-05-11  19:29:00        -1  22:15:00       -24         0      B6   
103994 2014-05-11  11:17:00         5  13:55:00         9         0      B6   
103995 2014-05-11  07:36:00       -10  09:24:00       -18         0      B6   
103996 2014-05-11  13:40:00         0  16:47:00        10         0      B6   

       tailnum flight origin dest air_time distance duration  
103992  N630JB    925    JFK  TPA      137     1005     1013  
103993  N632JB    225    JFK  TPA      137     1005     1929  
103994  N635JB    127    EWR  MCO      126      937     1117  
103995  N637JB   1273    JFK  CHS       92      636     0736  
103996  N637JB    213    JFK  LGB      352     2465     1340
```

With this data, I want to express dep_delay, arr_delay, air_time and duration as timedeltas, but I keep getting zeroed-out values? I'm using

```
data['air_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['air_time'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not just a display issue as this should work, also what are the units of these delays? the default unit is nanoseconds

Comment: `numpy.timedelta64(137,'ns')` is what you did.

Comment: They're hours and minutes interpreted from the right, so 9 is 9 minutes and 137 is 1 hr 37 minutes

Comment: Thst's a good point - I guess they must be just minutes and 137 must be 137 minutes

Comment: So how would I tell to_timedelta to interpret my data as minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are getting all `00:00:00.000000` values, then your `air_time` values might be strings. (You can check the data type of the `air_time` column by inspecting `data.info()`. If the dtype says `object` then the values are Python objects (such as `str`s) instead of a NumPy integer data type. You can then confirm they are strings by inspecting `set(map(type, data['air_time']))`.)

If they are strings, you can convert them to ints first by using:

```
data['air_time'] = data['air_time'].astype(int)
```

If 137 means 137 minutes then use

```
data['air_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['air_time'], unit='m', errors='coerce')
```

If, on the other hand, 137 means 1 hour and 37 minutes, then use

```
data['air_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(
    (data['air_time']//100)*60 + (data['air_time'] % 100), unit='m', 
    errors='coerce')
```

The [`unit='m'` argument](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) tells `pd.to_timedelta` to interpret the values as minutes.

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'air_time':['137','137','126','92','352']})
data['air_time'] = data['air_time'].astype(int)
data['air_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['air_time'], unit='m', errors='coerce')
```

yields

```
  air_time
0 02:17:00
1 02:17:00
2 02:06:00
3 01:32:00
4 05:52:00
```

---

Note that `pd.to_timedelta` can also accepts strings as input *if the strings contain the desired units*. For example,

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'air_time':['137','137','126','92','352']})
data['air_time'] = data['air_time'] + ' minutes'
#       air_time
# 0  137 minutes
# 1  137 minutes
# 2  126 minutes
# 3   92 minutes
# 4  352 minutes

data['air_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['air_time'], errors='coerce')
```

yields the same result.

Comment: I'm still getting 00:00:00.000000 in my air-time col with data['air_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['air_time'], unit='m', errors='coerce') ?

Comment: Ah, then your values are probably strings. Use `df['air_time'] = `df['air_time'].astype(int)` to convert the strings to ints first.

Comment: With my minus values I'm still getting -1 days +23:58:00 which is correct, but a bit confusing - can I make it format it as just - minutes?

Comment: Unfortunately, once you make the values `timedelta64`s, you lose control over the way the values are displayed (but you gain computational benefits). So for computation, use `timedelta64`s, but for display purposes, [convert (back) to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/190597).

Comment: Cool - I guess I'll handle it in my Django forms if I need to

Comment: Or, to avoid having to convert timedeltas back into strings/ints, you could keep `air_time` as it is (for display purposes), and assign the timedeltas to a new column: `data['air_timedelta'] = pd.to_timedelta(...)`.