# I want to change the time calculation format (django models, virtual field)

Tags: django, django-models, field, datetime-format

model field code is this

```
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    @property
    def now_diff(self):
        return timezone.now() - self.created
```

I have a question about django time circulation using virtual field

current output of time circulation is 5:26:34.349728

But I want to 5:26:34

Is there a way?

thanks for let me know ~!

i chaged to

```
    @property
    def now_diff(self):
        s=timezone.now() - self.created
        hours, remainder = divmod(s, 3600)
        minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
        return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
```

but error

```
TypeError: 'Todo' object is not subscriptable

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the ***microseconds*** from **`timedelta`** which you've got

```
from datetime import timedelta


class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def now_diff(self):
        delta = timezone.now() - self.created
        return str(delta - timedelta(microseconds=delta.microseconds))
```

---

For more readable solution,

```
from datetime import timedelta


def chop_microseconds(delta):
    return delta - timedelta(microseconds=delta.microseconds)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    @property
    def now_diff(self):
        return str(chop_microseconds(timezone.now() - self.created))
```

---

### Some BG things

If we look into the [Source code of **`__str__()`**](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/datetime.py#L603) function of **`timedelta`** class,

```
....
if self._microseconds:
    s = s + ".%06d" % self._microseconds
...
```

which converts the string representation of the timedelta object.
So, here we substract the ***microsecond*** from timedelta and hence solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try like this(mostly copy pasted from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539360/2696165) answer):

```
@property
def now_diff(self):
    time_delta = timezone.now() - self.created
    s = time_delta.seconds
    hours, remainder = divmod(s, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return '{:02}:{:02}:{:02}'.format(int(hours), int(minutes), int(seconds))
```