# Python - Timedelta to datetime with miliseconds -> "HH:MM:SS"

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

On this problem I keep getting stuck when trying several options provided.

In simple words, I'm running a script that has a starting time (several actually, based on different criteria) and in a loop I want to display the running time of that criteria in a JSON and put it in a program (using *requests*) that is updated every time the loop passes one of the criteria.

I was doing that by simply running:

```
starting_time = datetime.now() #but just a bit earlier in the script
now = datetime.now()
running_time = now-starting_time
```

This *running_time* is then used as a variable in a JSON, but that needs to be in the format of *'HH:MM:SS'* else my *requests* doesn't allow me to put. Which caused the problem for me, because it isn't possible to use strftime on a timedelta.

The timedelta might be based on miliseconds, but those are fine as *"00:00:00"*... but that caused me problems when trying to convert the timedelta to string first and then convert it back to a regular datetime.

What am I missing?

Comment: Adding or subtracting 2 datetime objects returns a timedelta-object. To format a timedelta-object see https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/2166778

Comment: Unfortunately the solution there --> str(timedelta) doesn't work, because after using datetime.strptime on that it doesn't work when the timedelta = 00:00:00.001001 --> ValueError: unconverted data remains: .001001

Answer (score 1):

A possible workaround would be:

```
starting_time = datetime.now()
now = datetime.now()
running_time = now-starting_time
x = datetime.timedelta(seconds=running_time.seconds)
result = str(x)
if result[1] == ":":
    result = "0"+result
print(result)
```

Here line 4 makes sure that x only has the seconds and ignores the miliseconds of running_time. Then we add a zero at the beginning in case needed.

But also see comment to better understand timedelta.

Comment: Thanks for your response! When I now use strptime(result) it adds 1900-01-01 infront of the time, is that common? --> datetime.strptime(result, "%H:%M:%S")

Comment: why do you need strptime? The variable result returns the what you need in HH:MM:SS format, doesn't it?