# sum up timestamps in values list in dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, timestamp

I have a dictionary having its values as timestamp. Few keys have list of timestamps as values.
I am trying to sum timestamps which is in value. But failing with below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 53, in <module>
    for key, value in total_exam_items.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

Below is my code:

```
total_items = {'item1': ['0:02:00'], 'item2': ['0:02:13'], 'item3': ['0:04:53'], 'item4': ['0:00:31', '0:05:17'], 'item5': ['0:04:31'], 'item6': ['0:04:34'], 'item6': ['0:13:26', '0:04:24']}
output = defaultdict(datetime)
for key, value in total_items.iteritems():
    output[key] += value
```

Not sure where I am doing wrong?
Any suggestions please???

Comment: try `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()`

Answer (score 2):

I think the point here (besides `.items()`) is that you need to use `timedelta` if you want the sum of the times at each item, e.g.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from datetime import timedelta
from pandas import to_timedelta

total_items = {'item1': ['0:02:00'], 'item2': ['0:02:13'], 'item3': ['0:04:53'], 'item4': ['0:00:31', '0:05:17'], 'item5': ['0:04:31'], 'item6': ['0:04:34'], 'item6': ['0:13:26', '0:04:24']}
output = defaultdict(timedelta)

for key, value in total_items.items():
    l = [to_timedelta(s) for s in value]
    for t in l:
        output[key] += t
        
# output
# defaultdict(datetime.timedelta,
#             {'item1': Timedelta('0 days 00:02:00'),
#              'item2': Timedelta('0 days 00:02:13'),
#              'item3': Timedelta('0 days 00:04:53'),
#              'item4': Timedelta('0 days 00:05:48'),
#              'item5': Timedelta('0 days 00:04:31'),
#              'item6': Timedelta('0 days 00:17:50')})
```

Note that I'm using `to_timedelta` from the `pandas` lib because it offers convenient parsing of timedeltas from string.

Comment: This logic is superb. But how do we remove upto `Timedelta('0 days ` in the output?

Comment: @SamudralaPrasad: unfortunately, there is no `strftime` for `timedelta, so you'll need a work-around; see [e.g. here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string) to get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Python3.x

instead of:

```
for key, value in total_items.iteritems():
```

Try:

```
for key, value in total_items.items():
```

Comment: I have tried using `items()`, but it is throwing error: `    output[key] += value
TypeError: function missing required argument 'year' (pos 1)`

Comment: @SamudralaPrasad that is the problem in total_items data values