# How to get hour format in two digit (00.00.00) in python?

Tags: python, datetime, iot, datetime-format, strftime

Below is the sample code I am using inside my one of the application. I want Default hour format as 00 (e.g. `02:30:35`) and here I am getting as `0:00:03.011445` so I am using `strftime` but I am getting another exception there. Please guide on it.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
from time import strftime
import time

start = datetime.now()
time.sleep(3)
end = datetime.now()

print(start)
print(end)
dt = (end - start)
print('Defual Time:', dt)

print('New Format DateTime', dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
```

I am getting below output.

```
2020-10-17 19:15:36.831928
2020-10-17 19:15:39.843373
Defualt Time: 0:00:03.011445
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/New folder/IoT2.py", line 30, in <module>
    print('New Format DateTime', dt.strftime("%m/%d/%y %H:%M:%S"))
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you are getting the Attribute Error is because `strftime` belongs to `datetime.datetime` class ( from `datetime.now()`) and not `datetime.timedelta` class (from `end-start`).

Instead, you can actually use `total_seconds()` method to fetch the seconds of the time difference and format it in string however you wish.

**Edit**: You can use `microseconds` attribute of `timedelta` to calculate your milliseconds and format it to display.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
from time import strftime
import time

start = datetime.now()
time.sleep(3)
end = datetime.now()

print(start)
print(end)
dt = (end - start)
print('Default Time:', dt)

milliseconds = int(round(dt.microseconds/1000, 1))

dt = int(dt.total_seconds())

print('New format: {:02}:{:02}:{:02}:{:03}'.format(dt // 3600, dt % 3600 // 60, dt % 60, milliseconds))
```

The output for this would be:

```
2020-10-19 13:02:13.861103
2020-10-19 13:02:16.863268
Default Time: 0:00:03.002165
New format: 00:00:03:002
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats cool... but one query is how to continue with milisconds? because I need entire milliseconds too...

Comment: For milliseconds, use `print(round(dt.microseconds/1000,2))` before converting dt type to int.

Comment: Hi, no its returning wrong value. like this. Milliseconds are not coming with new format.                                                           
2020-10-19 17:36:30.792681
2020-10-19 17:36:33.793254
Default Time: 0:00:03.000573
0.57
New format: 00:00:03

Comment: Hey, I have edited the code to include the millisecond format as required. Let me know if it solves your issue

Comment: Output of your code is                                                                                               
2020-10-19 19:19:42.015249
2020-10-19 19:19:45.016215
Default Time: 0:00:03.000966
New format: 00:00:03:001.  What we need that, the value in new format should 00:00:03.000966. One more thing.

Comment: Try this : `milliseconds = dt.microseconds

dt = int(dt.total_seconds())

print('New format: {:02}:{:02}:{:02}:{:06}'.format(dt // 3600, dt % 3600 // 60, dt % 60, milliseconds))`

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

u can just get seconds and days from a datetime.timedelta so u can do something like this!

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

start = datetime.now()
time.sleep(3)
end = datetime.now()

print(start)
print(end)
dt = (end - start)
print('Default Time:', dt)

def days_hours_minutes(td):
    x = (td.days, td.seconds//3600, (td.seconds//60)%60, td.seconds)
    return x #(days, hrs, mins, seconds)

print('New Format DateTime', days_hours_minutes(dt))
```

Comment: hope so my answer helps!

Comment: Thanks but it is returning something ;                                                                   
2020-10-19 10:28:55.604344
2020-10-19 10:28:58.609129
Default Time: 0:00:03.004785
New Format DateTime (0, 0, 0, 3)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method total_seconds of the timedelta object and calculate the respective hours minutes and second by yourself and then you can format the output string as you want.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import time
from time import strftime
import time

start = datetime.now()
time.sleep(3)
end = datetime.now()

print(start)
print(end)
dt = (end - start)
print('Defual Time:', dt)

dt_sec=dt.total_seconds()
hours,rem=divmod(dt_sec,3600)
minutes,rem=divmod(rem,60)

print('New Format DateTime', f'{hours:0>2.0f}:{minutes:0>2.0f}:{rem:0>2.0f}:'+f'{rem:.3f}'[-3:])
```

**Edit**

I added also the printing of the milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks. Thats cool... but one query is how to continue with milisconds? because I need entire milliseconds too...

Comment: Then you do the same but you should format the milllisecond with three digits instead of 2 of course.

Comment: No its not working. Can you tell where to change it exactly?