# Removing " x days " from datetime.timedelta object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format

I need to create a report where I need to subtract two dates and return it in the form of
%H:%M%S

This is the subtraction which I inserted into a list :

```
time_difference_temp=datetime.strptime(next_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") - datetime.strptime(current_time,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
time_difference.append(time_difference_temp)
return time_difference
```

this list returns to >

```
def push_to_csv(time_difference):
    df = pd.read_csv('time_differences.csv')
    df["Delta"] = time_difference
    df.dropna(subset=["Data"], inplace=True)
    df.to_csv("Final_ReportX.csv")
```

in the csv Final_ReportX it saved in the form :
0 days 00:05:39

**I need it to return just 00:05:39, no days.**

*regex is not an option

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a custom function that converts timedelta to H:M:S string:

```
def td_to_str(td):
    """
    convert a timedelta object td to a string in HH:MM:SS format.
    """
    hours, remainder = divmod(td.total_seconds(), 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return f'{int(hours):02}:{int(minutes):02}:{int(seconds):02}'

s = pd.Series(pd.to_timedelta(['1 day, 00:05:39']))

s.apply(td_to_str)
# 0    24:05:39
# dtype: object
```

- [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Thanks,that's a nice idea . I solved it by wrapping with str- time_difference.append(str(time_difference_temp))

Comment: @B.W.: if you know for sure you only have timedelta < 1 day then `str()` is fine ;-)