# How to remove 0 day for and keep time only in a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

Hi im having an issue with when converting the time into timedelta. I managed to keep the time only but it change to an object type. i would like to ask if you can assist me with keeping the time only in timedelta type. below is an example of my dataframe.
| Time           | ST |S|
| ---------------| ---|-|
| 0 days 12:09:46| 33 |R|
| 0 days 12:09:51| 45 |H|

i tried the following

```
  n['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(n['Time'])
# n['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(n['Time'], unit='s') # error unit must not be specified if the input contains a str
  n['Time'] = n['Time'].astype(str).str.split('0 days ').str[-1] # works but cant 
  resample the data 
  n= n.set_index('Time')#.resample('6s').mean()
```

It was working before when i chaned to a new laptop 0 days appeared

Thanks for your time and help

Comment: Concerning formatting to string, unfortunately, there's no "strftime" for timedeltas; you'll need a work-around like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/539360/10197418).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to drop the column S contacting strings before resampling then
0 days won't affect resampling nor plotting as it is the same across all rows in the data

```
n= n.drop(['s'], axis = 1)
n['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(n['Time']) 
n = n.set_index('Time')#.resample('6s').mean()
```

This works fine
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though there is no direct method to do that as of now, but it can still be done by following the below example:-

```
import pandas as pd
time_range = pd.timedelta_range("00:00:00", "20:00:00", periods=6)
```

The time_range is a timedelta index object which has "0 day" attached to the time range you are looking for, now in order to remove 0 day. Do

```
lt=time_range.format(date_format = "%H:%m:%s")
lt = [i[7:] for i in lt]
```

lt is the list containing the timerange.