# Python Pandas Working with Timedelta then saving it to csv

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am trying to transition my reports that are currently automated with VBA to python.
But since i work with lots of durations on my exports I have a problem.

If i want to do some measures with this data that is in "%H:%M:%S" format I have to convert it using:

`df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])`

But when I save my dataframe back to csv it saves the data as `0 days 00:09:17.000000000` and I need it to be saved with the format %H:%M:%S.

Am I doing it wrong? Thanks

Comment: You could create a column that has the string representation you want before you save. If you are opening it in Excel, maybe you can format the column in Excel.

Comment: If the duration can be more than 24 hours, there will be a 'n days' prefix if converted to string.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8907269/15070697) for a customized formatting.

Comment: if you want a specific format for `timedelta`, write your own function that formats to string. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66278958/10197418).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time Delta is difference between 2 dates/time so that's why it saves data as

```
0 days 00:09:17.000000000
```

If you want to save data as `00:09:17.000000000` then
After you run

```
df['Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Duration'])
```

then convert its `dtype` to `string` by:-

```
df['Duration'] = df['Duration'].astype('str')
```

and finally:-

```
df['Duration']=df['Duration'].apply(lambda x:x.split(' ')[2])
```

**Note:- it store data as object type not timedelta type**