# Change timedelta format to show minutes and seconds only

Tags: python

I would like to change the format of timedelta print

```
    end_time = time()
    r_time = (end_time - start_time)
    m = "{}".format(str(timedelta(seconds=r_time)))
```

Currently I'm getting `00:00:00` and will like to change for `00.00` , just minutes and seconds

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
`timedelta` formats are documented quite well; we expect you to incorporate that knowledge into your question.

Comment: Do you want/need to convert the hours component into minutes, or just drop it?

Comment: @mhawke just drop it
just need minutes and second and `.` as separator

Comment: There's lots of info on this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string

Comment: @mar24n: you should add your `divmod()` solution as an answer.

Comment: @mhavke ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another solution

```
r_time = (end_time - start_time)

seconds = abs(int(r_time))

minutes, seconds = divmod(seconds, 60)
times = '%i.%i' % (minutes, seconds)
```

That's gave me exactly the format what i was looking for
`00.00`

Comment: What happens when `r_time` > 3599?

Comment: good question :) , but in my use case of this , the `r_time` will never be greater then `1800`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do much in terms of formatted string conversions with a `timedelta`. You could just convert to a string and grab the last 5 characters:

```
>>> r_time = 1000
>>> str(timedelta(seconds=r_time))[-5:]
'16:40'
```

Other, less hacky ways exist such as the following which does not require mucking about with `timedelta`:

```
>>> time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(r_time))
'16:40'
>>> time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(3599))
'59:59'
>>> time.strftime('%M:%S', time.gmtime(3600))
'00:00'
```

I was tempted by this:

```
>>> r_time = 1000
>>> f'{r_time//60:02}:{r_time%60:02}'
'16:40'
```

but then this happens:

```
>>> r_time = 3600
>>> f'{r_time//60:02}:{r_time%60:02}'
'60:00'
```

Comment: `>>> f'{r_time//60}:{r_time%60}'
'16:40'` that's looks good , but unfortunately in my case i can't use `fstring` with `Micropython`