# How can I make the datetime display as integers(second)___python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I want to make a Timer,
but display is 0:00:00.000000
how can change display is 0:00:00

```
import time, datetime
import tkinter as tk
import time, datetime



win = tk.Tk()
win.geometry('200x100+550+250')
win.title('Timer')
win.config(bg='#323232')
win.attributes('-topmos', 1)

start = datetime.datetime.now()

frame = tk.Frame()

lab = tk.Label(text='', bg='#000000', fg='#FFFFFF')
lab.pack()


def update():
    dur = datetime.datetime.now() - start
    lab.config(text=dur)
    frame.after(20, update)
```

Start Button : when click button will start timer

```
St_button = tk.Button(text='Start', command=update)
St_button.pack()

frame.mainloop()
```

Comment: `dur` is a timedelta object, you might want to have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/10197418

Answer (score 0):

The obvious and easy way is

```
    lab.config(text=str(dur)[:7])
```