# Extracting year, month, day, hour and minute from the current datetime

Tags: python, python-datetime

I need to extract year, month, day, hour and possible also minutes from the current datetime:

```py
import datetime
from datetime import datetime
    
now = datetime.now() 
date_t = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

trying

```py
date_t.day()
date_t.month()
date_t.year()
date_t.hour()
date_t.minute()
```

It does not work as I have an error: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'year'`.
I hope you can help

Comment: Does this has anything related with `pandas`? If not, pls remove this unrelated tag.

Comment: just removed it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `now`. And no parenths.

```py
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()

print(now.day)
print(now.month)
print(now.year)
print(now.hour)
print(now.minute)
```

Comment: Thank you Safwan. Do you know why replacing these values into: 
`rt =  datetime.datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour)` I get `AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'`? (In 8 minutes I will mark your answer. It is currently not allowing me)

Comment: After the line `from datetime import datetime`, `datetime` is actually `datetime.datetime`. If you want the core `datetime` module, I suggest you add this line, too - `import datetime as dt`. But the function you're using does not require the core module, it requires only `datetime.datetime`. So change your code to `datetime(now.year,now.month,now.day,now.hour)`. Not that I see much use in it, you can do `datetime.now()` instead.

Comment: Thank you Safwan. The problem is something in the format, I guess. Following this answer (replacing the date into the reftime (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038185/from-string-to-datetime-looking-at-the-current-local-time), it returns no values

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
now.day
now.month
now.year
now.hour
now.minute
```

your `date_t` is a String where you've formatted the date.  `now` is a `date time` object

Answer (score 2):

DateTime uses certain formatting. %d means day, %m means months. %Y means year. So on and so forth!

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
date_total = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
day = now.strftime("%d")
month = now.strftime("%m")
year = now.strftime("%Y")
hour = now.strftime("%H")
minute = now.strftime("%M")
print(day) # you can change this to whatever you want now, as I've set different vairables to different date formats
```

This is not the prettiest formatting, but it works. You can just use:

```
import datetime
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() 
print(now.hour) # 'hour' can be changed to what you need.
```

In response to an error you're explaining in comments below:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

means you do not have to do 'datetime.datetime'