# Converting Date and time to UNIX date format

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I have been trying to convert the date and time given in following format "2021/12/04 11:10:00.000" to UNIX time.I have attached the sample of my program I tried. It does provide me the UNIX time but when I checked for the converted UNIX time it didn't gave me the correct UNIX time conversion.

```
for i in dx['date']:
year= i[0:4]
month = i[5:7]
day = i[8:10]
hr = i[11:13]
minute = i[14:16]
sec = i[17:19]
time = year+','+month+','+day+','+hr+','+minute+','+sec
print("Debug", time)
unixtime = datetime.datetime(int(year),int(month),int(day),int(hr),int(minute),int(sec)).timestamp()
```

Comment: Don't mangle datetimeS yourself, use a library like `datetime` and its format specifiers. Trying to handle datetimeS yourself almost always results in bugs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/67778507/4583620

Comment: To address your "incorrect" UNIX time, `.timestamp()` assumes local timezone is being converted but the returned timestamp is relative to the epoch 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert string datetime to datetime obj, and then retrieve timestamp.

```
from datetime import datetime
t = "2021/12/04 11:10:00.000"
dt = datetime.strptime(t, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
dt.timestamp()
```

Output:

> 1638637800.0

Comment: Please refrain from answering common duplicates.

Comment: as long as that is tolerated officially, people will keep doing it.