# Converting one column of a dataframe from minute to hhmm and hh:mm format in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a data frame named 'df' where the column 'A' contains the time from 0 to 1440 minutes in a day. I want to add extra columns having the same time in hhmm format and hh:mm format. How can I do that in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert values to timedeltas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[10,20,1440, 0]})

df['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['A'], unit='min')
print (df)
                A
0 0 days 00:10:00
1 0 days 00:20:00
2 1 days 00:00:00
3 0 days 00:00:00
```

For formating use:

```
def f(x):
    ts = x.total_seconds()
    hours, remainder = divmod(ts, 3600)
    minutes, seconds = divmod(remainder, 60)
    return ('{:02d}:{:02d}').format(int(hours), int(minutes)) 

df['A'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['A'], unit='min').apply(f)
print (df)
       A
0  00:10
1  00:20
2  24:00
3  00:00
```

Comment: basically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/10197418) - you might want to use an f-string for the better looks (and up-to-date-ness) ;-)