# In dataframe: how to pull minutes and seconds combinedly(mm:ss) from timedelta using python

Tags: python, timedelta

i have already tried these but by this we can only get hour/minute/second but not both minute and second

In[7]:
df['B'] = df['A'].dt.components['hours']

df

Out[7]:

```
     A  B
```

0 02:00:00  2

1 01:00:00  1

---

from this timedelta format

0        0 days 00:02:02.246000

1        0 days 00:01:59.127000

i need only minutes and seconds, how to get it as below

02:02

01:59

Comment: You'll have to write your own formatter; see [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the timedelta to total seconds and use divmod function to extract minutes and seconds from the total seconds.

Edit: Removed lambda function from the first operation.

```
    df['sec'] = df['A'].dt.total_seconds().astype(int)
    df['B'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(divmod(divmod(row['sec'], 3600)[1], 60)[0]).zfill(2)+':'+str(divmod(divmod(row['sec'], 3600)[1], 60)[1]).zfill(2), axis=1)
```