# How to substrat two timedate columns in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

These are two columns(A & B) in a python data frame

column df['A']

0         2021-05-19 11:21:29.463

1         2021-05-19 11:21:39.127

column df['B']

0         2021-05-19 11:19:27.217

1         2021-05-19 11:19:40.000

by subtracting these two columns df['A'] - df['B'] I need to get minutes and seconds

02:02

01:59

or at least below format

00:02:02

00:01:59

Comment: please don't [duplicate your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68081772/10197418) -  and see my comment there.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(df['B'])
def date_string(a,b):
    td = (a - b)/np.timedelta64(1, 's')
    td = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=td))
    return(td[:-7])
df['diff'] = df.apply(lambda x: date_string(x.A, x.B), axis=1)
```

Comment: not need for typecasting here; subtracting the two datetime columns already gives you timedelta. btw. the OP is looking to *format* the output as well

Comment: Not sure I understand. Isn't that the format they wanted? Also, are you assuming that the dates are already in datetime format? If they came from an excel file that might not be the case. @MrFuppes

Comment: conversion to datetime might be necessary, yes. but timedelta is not a format, it's a datatype. the OP wants a format "HH:MM:SS" or "MM:SS" (the datatype would be string then).

Comment: @MrFuppes and OP. I have changed my answer in response to comments.

Comment: Please accept my answer if it has solved your problem.