# python pandas: substracting two datetimes gives zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

```
df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime( df['time'], format = "%H:%M:%S", errors="coerce") #create datetime
df['timestart'] = df.iloc[[0]]['time2'] #create start time
df['timediff'] = ( df['time2'] - df['timestart']) #substract start_time from current time
```

But all I get is

Name: time2, dtype: datetime64[ns]

| time | time2 | timestart | timediff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 09:00:00 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 0 days |
| 10:10:00 | 1900-01-01 10:10:00 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 0 days |
| 11:08:00 | 1900-01-01 11:08:00 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 0 days |
| 12:12:00 | 1900-01-01 12:12:00 | 1900-01-01 09:00:00 | 0 days |

"0 days" isn't what I expect. I need

```
00:00:00
01:10:00
02:08:00
etc.
```

Comment: take the `.dt.total_seconds()` and format those to a string as `HH:MM:SS`? see [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/10197418).

Comment: btw. you can do directly `df['timediff'] = df['time2'] - df.iloc[[0]]['time2']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(["09:00:00","10:10:00","11:08:00","12:12:00","13:09:00","14:09:00","15:09:00","16:01:00","16:46:00"]),columns=['time'])
df['time2'] = pd.to_datetime( df['time'], format = "%H:%M:%S", errors="coerce")
starttime = df['time2'].iloc[0]
df['timediff'] = (df['time2'] - starttime )
```

If you want total seconds then you can use:

```
df['timediff']=df['timediff'].dt.total_seconds()
```

If you needed only time part then(you don't care about days):

```
df['timediff']=pd.to_datetime(df['timediff'].dt.total_seconds(),unit='s').dt.time
```

output of `df`:

```
     time       time2                   timestart               timediff
0   09:00:00    1900-01-01 09:00:00     1900-01-01 09:00:00     0 days 00:00:00
1   10:10:00    1900-01-01 10:10:00     1900-01-01 09:00:00     0 days 01:10:00
2   11:08:00    1900-01-01 11:08:00     1900-01-01 09:00:00     0 days 02:08:00
3   12:12:00    1900-01-01 12:12:00     1900-01-01 09:00:00     0 days 03:12:00
```

Comment: Nope, same result

Comment: @AlexanderWeixelbaumer Updated answer kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: 'timestart =df.loc[0,'time2']

Results in "KeyError: 'the label [0] is not in the [index]'"

Comment: @AlexanderWeixelbaumer updated  answer...Kindly have a look

Comment: @MrFuppes I saw your comment

Comment: @AlexanderWeixelbaumer updated answer...Kindly have a look

Comment: no offense, just wanted to point out that taking `dt.time` might give unexpected results if the timedelta is greater 24 hours.

Comment: @MrFuppes Thank you Sir for noticing as you are right so behalfing of this made changes in answer ***:)***