# How to add times that has HH:MM:SS,XX format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, timedelta

My expertise lack when it comes to understanding this time format. I am guessing the `,XXX` is `XXX/1000` of a second?

Nevertheless I am trying to add a text files that contains time stamp like these and sum up the total.

Below is an example,

```
00:03:33,950
00:03:34,590
```

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure how to add up the last part

```
Hours = s.split(":")[0]
Minutes = s.split(":")[1]
Seconds = (s.split(":")[2]).split(",")[0]
Total_seconds = (Hours * 3600) + (Minutes * 60) + (Seconds)

Total_Time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=Total_seconds))
```

Comment: @Sayse thanks! adding that to my arsenal :)

Comment: `strptime` (p for parse) might be able to help, but I'm not sure how it's going to work with timedeltas.

Comment: @Norrius strptime/strftime don't work with timedeltas, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/538666/10197418

Answer (score 0):

Reed this [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/time.html) about time.strftime() format

For example

```
from time import gmtime, strftime
strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())

--'Thu, 28 Jun 2001 14:17:15 +0000'--
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this answers this question. ```strftime("00:03:33,950", gmtime())``` would give me ```00:03:33,950```...

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're halfway there.

All you have to do is to to convert your `str`s into `int` and pass them as parameters to the appropriate `timedelta` keywords.

```py
from datetime import timedelta

Hours = int(s.split(":")[0])
Minutes = int(s.split(":")[1])
Seconds = int((s.split(":")[2]).split(",")[0])
Milliseconds = int((s.split(":")[2]).split(",")[1])

duration = timedelta(hours=Hours, minutes=Minutes, seconds=Seconds, milliseconds=Milliseconds)
```

After adding all the durations you need, `str()` the final `timedelta` object.

```
>>> durations_1 = timedelta(hours=2,milliseconds=750)
>>> durations_2 = timedelta(milliseconds=251)
>>> durations_sum = durations_1 + durations_2
>>> str(durations_sum)
'2:00:01.001000'
>>> str(durations_sum).replace('.',',')
'2:00:01,001000'
```