# AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, attributeerror

I'm self-learning how to code in Python.

I'm trying to code a "Calculator" that calculates how many hours/days I need to work to buy a product. I got this error and don't know how to fix it:

```
  File "D:\---\---\---\code.py", line 21, in <module>
    print("Para comprar um produto de " + str(preco) + " tem de trabalhar durante " + str(resultado.strftime("%d dias, %H horas e %M minutos.")))
AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object has no attribute 'strftime'
```

Here is the entire code:

```
import datetime

while True:
    questao = input("Quer calcular em horas ou em dias?\nH ou D: ") 
    if questao == "H":
        salario = float(input("\nQuanto ganha por hora? "))
        preco = float(input("Quanto custa o produto? "))
        divisão = preco/salario
        resultado = datetime.timedelta(hours=divisão)
        break
    elif questao == "D":
        salario = float(input("\nQuanto ganha por dia? "))
        preco = float(input("Quanto custa o produto? "))
        divisão = preco/salario
        resultado = datetime.timedelta(days=divisão)
        break
    else:
        print("Inseriu algo que não existe, tente novamente!\n")
        continue

print("Para comprar um produto de " + str(preco) + " tem de trabalhar durante " + str(resultado.strftime("%d dias, %H horas e %M minutos.")))
```

Can someone help me fix this? Thanks :)

Comment: timedeltas don't have a strftime method, there are examples for doing that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Format timedelta to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538666/format-timedelta-to-string)

Comment: Now I understand what I have to do, but I don't know how to do it with my variable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `.days` value from the `timedelta`, and the seconds.  Unlike other `datetime` objects, using .hour doesn't work.  Then do math on the seconds to get hours and minutes.  You can also just convert it to string if that's easier.

```
preco = 1000
salario = 6
divisão = preco / salario
resultado = datetime.timedelta(hours=divisão)  # 6 days, 22:40:00
print(str(resultado))
# 6 days, 22:40:00

days = resultado.days
seconds = resultado.seconds

hours = seconds//3600
minutes = (seconds//60) % 60

print(str(days), 'dias', str(hours), 'horas e', str(minutes), 'minutos.')
# 6 dias 22 horas e 40 minutos.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to format YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS then this code just copy paste

def format_timedelta(td):
# Calculate components
days = abs(td.days)
minutes, seconds = divmod(td.seconds, 60)
hours, remainder = divmod(minutes, 60)

```
# Calculate years and months
years, days_in_year = divmod(days, 365)
months, days_in_month = divmod(days_in_year, 30)

# Create the formatted string
formatted_string = (
    "{year:02d}:{month:02d}:{day:02d}:{hour:02d}:{min:02d}:{sec:02d}".format(
        year=abs(int(years)),
        month=int(months),
        day=int(days_in_year),
        hour=int(hours),
        min=int(remainder),
        sec=int(seconds),
    )
)

return formatted_string
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).